# Strenuous, arduous, laborious, onerous sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1n{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac1k}\right)^3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1n{\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac1k}\right)^3$$

I want to see what this converges to. Obviously it converges on inspection.

Any suggestions on methods to use?

Comment: Have you tried [summagrating by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts)?

Comment: $$\frac{31 \pi ^6}{5040}-\frac{5 \zeta (3)^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$S:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(H_n)^3}{n^3}$$ 
is convergent since the terms are equivalent to $\,\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}n\right)^3\,$ as $\;n\to \infty\,$ and given by $$S=\frac {31}{5040}\pi^6-\frac 52\zeta(3)^2\\\approx 2.3009545517005250398$$
I don't know a complete proof but we may start with the following class of Euler sums :
$$s_h(m,n):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(H_k)^m}{(k+1)^n}$$
($H_k$ is the $k$-th harmonic number)

and rewrite your sum as :
\begin{align}
S&=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(H_{k+1})^3}{(k+1)^3}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\left(H_k+\frac 1{k+1}\right)^3}{(k+1)^3}\\
&=1+s_h(3,3)+3\,s_h(2,4)+3\,s_h(1,5)+\zeta(6)-1\\
\end{align}
Using the expressions tabulated in the $1994$ paper from Bailey, Borwein and Girgensohn ["Experimental Evaluation of Euler Sums"](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/dhbpapers/eulsum-em.pdf) this becomes :
$$S=\left(-\frac{33}{16}\zeta(6)+2\,\zeta(3)^2\right)+3\,\left(\frac 23\zeta(6)-\frac 13\zeta(2)\zeta(4)+\frac 13\zeta(2)^3-\zeta(3)^2\right)\\+3\,\left(\frac 52\,\zeta(6)-\frac 12(2\,\zeta(4)\zeta(2)+\zeta(3)^2)\right)+\zeta(6)$$

$s_h(3,3)$ was only an experimental result when the paper initially appeared but proved since them (as indicated in the updated paper). Anyway a more direct derivation should remain of interest !

Proofs concerning $\;\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(H_n)^2}{n^2}\;$ are provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554003/a-closed-form-for-the-sum-sum-n-1-infty-left-frach-nn-right2).

Comment: Brilliant!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks @900sit-upsaday ! (even if the hard work belongs to others...). I computed the next series of the kind $\;\displaystyle S_m:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(H_n)^m}{n^m}\;$ (i.e. $S_4$ and $S_5$) to $200$ digits but it seems that the result is more complicated than simple sums of products of $\zeta(\text{integer})\,$ (to order $2\,m$). Fine continuation anyway,

Answer (score 1):

It converges quite quickly, so using a computer can give you the sum.

For example in R

```
n <- 1:2^20
H <- cumsum(1/n)
S <- cumsum((H/n)^3)
S[2^20]
```

gives about `2.300955` though I suspect it is in fact just over $2.30095455$.

Alternatively use a good expansion of the Harmonic numbers, but I doubt this would be much more informative.

Comment: Any idea of what it could be ? If the exponent is $2$ instead of $3$, the result would have been the beautiful $\frac{17 \pi ^4}{360}$ which is very close to twice your result !