# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^n}{k(n-k)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation-method

Mathematica gives  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^n}{k(n-k)}=0.480453...$$
The question is: Can one get a closed form for this summation by hand?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148/get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29362/the-underlying-process-of-integrate/

Comment: @DanielS.: What's the idea with these links? The OP says that Mathematica only gives a numerical approximation, so if you meant to show how to get Mathematica to show its steps, that wouldn't be of much use here.

Comment: The sum should start at $n=2$.

Answer (score 3):

Simply interchange the order of summation. Indeed, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^n}{k(n-k)} &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{k(n-k)} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+m}}{km}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m}\\
&= \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\right)^2\\
&= (\ln 2)^2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

With

$$
\frac1{k(n-k)}=\frac1n\left(\frac1k+\frac1{n-k}\right)
$$

we can rewrite the sum as

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^n}{k(n-k)}
&=&
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac1k+\frac1{n-k}\right)
\\
&=&
2\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{n-1}}n\;,
\\
&=&
2\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}n-2\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac1{n^2}
\\
&=&
2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}n+\frac{\pi^2}6\;,
\end{eqnarray}

where $H_k$ is the $k$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/554118) by Sangchul Lee to [Infinite Series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{H_n}n\right)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554003) we have

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}nz^n=-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac z{z-1}\right)\;,
$$

and substituting $z=-1$ yields

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}n
&=&
-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)
\\
&=&
\frac12\left(\log^22-\frac{\pi^2}6\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Thus your sum evaluates to $\log^22$, in agreement with the numerical result.

With hindsight, we should have recognized that your sum is just the square of the series

$$
\log2=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac1n\;,
$$

computed as the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).