# Polygamma function series: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\left(\Psi^{(1)}(k)\right)^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, inequality, special-functions

Applying the [Copson's inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CopsonsInequality.html), I found:
$$S=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\left(\Psi^{(1)}(k)\right)^2\lt\dfrac{2}{3}\pi^2$$ where
$\Psi^{(1)}(k)$ is the polygamma function.
Is it known any sharper bound for the sum $S$?
Thanks.

Comment: You can try this bound $\zeta(2)+2\zeta(3)$.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The upper bound can be improved using asymptofic series :

[image]

Answer (score 34):

First, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\psi'(n)
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(k+n)^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\psi'(n)^2
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{j=n}^\infty\frac1{j^2}\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=n}^\infty\frac1{j^4}+2\sum_{j=n}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{j^2}\frac1{(j+m)^2}\right)\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^j\frac1{j^4}+2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^j\frac1{j^2}\frac1{(j+m)^2}\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{j^3}+2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{j(j+m)^2}\tag{5}\\
&=\zeta(3)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n^2}\tag{6}\\
&=\zeta(3)-2\zeta(3)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^2}\tag{7}\\[9pt]
&=\zeta(3)-2\zeta(3)+4\zeta(3)\tag{8}\\[18pt]
&=3\zeta(3)\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: use $(1)$
$(3)$: first sum covers $j=k$ the other $j\lt k$ and $j\gt k$
$(4)$: change order of summation
$(5)$: sum in $n$
$(6)$: $n=j+m$ and $j=n-m$ and sum in $m$
$(7)$: $H_{n-1}=H_n-\frac1n$
$(8)$: equation $(14)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/469785) with $q=2$
$(9)$: add

Comment: Nice answer without integrals! +1

Answer (score 27):

You may evaluate your series in closed form.

Here are the steps.

Recall the following standard representation for the digamma function:
$$
\psi(x) = -\gamma+\int_0^1 \frac{1 - t^{x-1}}{1 - t}{\rm{d}} x, \quad x>0,
$$
giving, by differentiation,
$$
\psi'(x) = -\int_0^1 \frac{t^{x-1} \ln t}{1 - t}{\rm{d}} x, \quad x>0.
$$
One may deduce
$$
\left(\psi'(k)\right)^2 = \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{(uv)^{k-1} \ln u\ln v}{(1 - u)(1-v)}{\rm{d}}u \:{\rm{d}} v
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\psi'(k)\right)^2 = \int_0^1 \! \!\int_0^1 \frac{\ln u\ln v}{(1-uv)(1 - u)(1-v)}{\rm{d}} u\:{\rm{d}} v
$$
By partial fraction decomposition and successive integrations involving $\text{Li}_{2}(\cdot)$, you arrive at 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\psi'(k)\right)^2 = 3\zeta(3) = 3.60617070947878285619921 \cdots.
$$

Comment: Very nice: equality is the sharpest bound of all!

Comment: @Semiclassical It's a great statement !!!.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but shouldn't the first line be $\psi(x)=-\gamma+\int^1_0\frac{1-t^{x-1}}{1-t}{\rm d}x$ instead? Of course, this doesn't affect the accuracy of your answer in any way. :)

Comment: @SuperAbound Typo corrected. Thank you!

Comment: This is quite beautiful.

Answer (score 21):

Continuing from Olivier Oloa's answer,

$$ \begin{align}  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \big(\psi^{(1)} (k) \big)^{2} &= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln u \ln v}{(1-uv)(1-u)(1-v)} \ du \ dv \\ &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln v}{(1-v)^{2}} \int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{\ln u}{1-u} - \frac{v \ln u}{1-vu} \right) \ du \ dv \\ &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln v}{(1-v)^{2}} \left( \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln u}{1-u} \ du - v \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln u}{1-vu} \ du\right) \ dv \end{align}$$

where $$  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln u}{1-u} \ du = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln (1-w)}{w} = -\text{Li}_{2}(1) = -\zeta(2) $$

and

$$  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln u}{1-vu} \ du = - \frac{1}{v}  \ln(1-vu) \ln u \Bigg|^{1}_{0} + \frac{1}{v} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln (1-vu)}{u} \ du  = - \frac{\text{Li}_{2}(v)}{v} .$$

Therefore,

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \big(\psi^{(1)} (k) \big)^{2} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln v}{(1-v)^2} \Big(\text{Li}_{2}(v) - \zeta(2) \Big) \ dv .$$

Then integrating by parts,

$$ \begin{align} &= \big(\text{Li}_{2}(v) - \zeta(2) \big) \left(\ln (1-v) + \frac{v \ln v}{1-v} \right)\Bigg|^{1}_{0} + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^{2}(1-v)}{v} \ dv + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-v) \ln v}{1-v} \ dv \\ &=  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^{2}(1-v)}{v} \ dv + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{ \ln(1-v) \ln v}{1-v} \ dv \end{align}$$

where $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^{2}(1-v)}{v} \ dt &= \ln^{2}(1-v)\ln v \Bigg|^{1}_{0} + 2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-v) \ln v}{1-v} \ dv \\ &=  2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{ \ln(1-v) \ln v}{1-v} \ dv . \end{align} $$

Therefore, $$ \begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \big(\psi^{(1)} (k) \big)^{2} &= 3 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-v) \ln v}{1-v} \ dv \\ &= -3 \int_{0}^{1} \ln v \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_{n}v^{n} \ dv  \\ & = -3 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_{n} \int_{0}^{1} v^{n} \ln v \ dv \\ &= 3 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{(n+1)^{2}} \\ &= 3 \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n+1}}{(n+1)^{2}}  - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)^{3}} \right) \\ &= 3 \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{n^{2}} -1  - \zeta(3) + 1 \right) \\ &= 3 \big(2 \zeta(3) - \zeta(3) \big) \tag{1} \\ &= 3 \zeta(3)  .\end{align} $$

$ $

$(1)$ [Generalized Euler sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469023/generalized-euler-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nnq)

Comment: Thank you for these details!

Comment: @OlivierOloa You're welcome.