# A closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \psi^{(1)} (k+a)\psi^{(1)} (k+b)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, closed-form, polygamma

The following [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882621/polygamma-function-series-displaystyle-sum-k-1-infty-left-psi1k/883750#883750)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\psi^{(1)} (k)\right)^2 = 3\zeta(3)
$$ where $\psi^{(1)}$ is the [polygamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.15) makes me think there is a nice sum for the series

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\psi^{(1)} (k+a)\right)^2 
> $$

or

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty \psi^{(1)} (k+a)\psi^{(1)} (k+b)
> $$

where $a$ and $b$ are any real numbers such that $a >-1, b>-1.$

Could you help me to find it?

Comment: Didn' t you answer it in your [given link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882621/polygamma-function-series-displaystyle-sum-k-1-infty-left-psi1k/883750#883750) ?.

Comment: If one proceeds along the same lines as that result, it seems that all one needs is a general result for the integral $$\int_0^1 \! \!\int_0^1 \frac{u^a v^b \ln u\ln v}{(1-uv)(1 - u)(1-v)}{\rm{d}} u\:{\rm{d}} v.$$ (That, of course, presumes that this integral is tractable...)

Comment: @FelixMarin: I think that result only covered the $a=b=0$ case?

Comment: @Semiclassical It looks like a hard one even with ${\rm Li_{\, s}\left(z\right)}$ machinery. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe through the identity: $$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\psi'(k)\, x^k = \frac{x}{6-6x}\left(\pi^2-6\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\right).$$

Comment: A trick which might come in handy is the [Feynman parametrization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization), since it allows one to convert the denominator into a linear combination of $u$ and $v$ (at the cost of introducing new integrations which are hopefully easier than those before.)

Comment: You know of at last two special cases

Comment: Also appear to have $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\psi^{(1)} (k+1)\right)^2 = 3\zeta(3) - \zeta(2)^2$

Comment: @BenedictWilliamJohnIrwin Sure, by putting $n=k+1$, one gets $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\psi^{(1)} (k+1)\right)^2=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\psi^{(1)} (n)\right)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\psi^{(1)} (n)\right)^2-\left(\psi^{(1)} (1)\right)^2$ $=3\zeta(3) - \zeta(2)^2$ which is equivalent to the hyperlink given at the beginning of my above question. Thank you.

Comment: Based on that Mathematica has suggested that, 
$$
S_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\psi^{(1)}(k+n))^2 = 3\zeta(3)-\kappa_{n+1}
$$
with $\kappa_n$ given by the recurrence
$$
\kappa_1=0\\
\kappa_2=\zeta(2)^2\\
\kappa_3=\zeta(2)^2+(\zeta(2)-1)^2\\
\kappa_n=\frac{13 + 2ng_5 + g_3^4 g_2^2 \kappa_{n-3} - g_3^2 g_2^2 (22-16n+3n^2) \kappa_{n-2} + g_3^2 g_2^2 (17-14n+3n^2) \kappa_{n-1}}{g_3^2 g_2^4}
$$
where $g_k=(n-k)$.

Comment: This gives
$$
S_2=3\zeta(3)-2\zeta(2)^2+2\zeta(2)-1\\
S_3=3\zeta(3)-3\zeta(2)^2+\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)-\frac{41}{16}\\
S_4=3\zeta(3)-4\zeta(2)^2+\frac{65}{9}\zeta(2)-\frac{2861}{648}\\
S_5=3\zeta(3)-5\zeta(2)^2+\frac{725}{72}\zeta(2)-\frac{133577}{20736}\\
$$
which seem to check out numerically.

Comment: @BenedictWilliamJohnIrwin Wow. That is a pretty amazing result. I would love to see some development of this discovery!

Comment: It is not too difficult to show that

$$S_n = 3 \zeta(3) - n\zeta(2)^2 +2(nH_{n-1,2} - H_{n-1})\zeta(2) - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}H_{k,2}^2,$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$-th Harmonic number and $H_{n,2} = \sum_i^n 1/i^2$

Comment: Perhaps there could be a similar formula for general $a$ that uses generalized Harmonic numbers?

Answer (score 6):

We have
$$
\int^{1}_{0}\int^{1}_{0}\frac{\log u\log v}{(1-uv)(1-u)(1-v)}dudv=3\zeta(3)
$$
Also
$$
\int^{1}_{0}\int^{1}_{0}\frac{(uv)^k\log u\log v}{(1-u)(1-v)}dudv=Z(2,k+1)\psi'(k+1)\textrm{, where }Re(k)>-1
$$
The function $Z(s,k)=\sum^{\infty}_{l=0}\frac{1}{(l+k)^s}$ is Hurwitz zeta function.
Hence
$$
\sum^{a-1}_{k=0}\int^{1}_{0}\int^{1}_{0}\frac{(uv)^k\log u\log v}{(1-u)(1-v)}dudv
=\int^{1}_{0}\int^{1}_{0}\frac{(1-(uv)^a)\log u\log v}{(1-uv)(1-u)(1-v)}dudv.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\left(\psi'(k+a)\right)^2=\int^{1}_{0}\int^{1}_{0}\frac{(uv)^a\log u \log v}{(1-u v)(1-u)(1-v)}dudv=3\zeta(3)-\sum^{a-1}_{k=0}Z(2,k+1)\psi'(k+1)
$$
By trying to generalize the problem we have
$$
C_{\nu}=\underbrace{\int^{1}_{0}\ldots\int^{1}_{0}}_{\nu}\frac{\log u_1\ldots \log u_{\nu}du_1\ldots du_{\nu}}{(1-u_1\ldots u_{\nu})(1-u_1)\ldots(1-u_{\nu})}=\sum^{\infty}_{l=0}\left(\int^{1}_{0}\frac{u^l\log u}{1-u}du\right)^{\nu}=
$$
$$
=\sum^{\infty}_{l=0}\left(-Z(2,l+1)\right)^{\nu}
$$
Also
$$
\underbrace{\int^{1}_{0}\ldots\int^{1}_{0}}_{\nu}\frac{u_1^k\ldots u_{\nu}^k \log u_1\ldots\log u_{\nu}du_1\ldots du_{\nu}}{(1-u_1)\ldots (1-u_{\nu})}=(-1)^{\nu}Z(2,k+1)(\psi'(k+1))^{\nu-1}
$$
Hence
$$
\sum^{a-1}_{k=0}\underbrace{\int^{1}_{0}\ldots\int^{1}_{0}}_{\nu}\frac{u_1^k\ldots u_{\nu}^k \log u_1\ldots\log u_{\nu}du_{1}\ldots du_{\nu}}{(1-u_1)\ldots (1-u_{\nu})}=(-1)^{\nu}\sum^{a-1}_{k=0}Z(2,k+1)(\psi'(k+1))^{\nu-1}=
$$
$$
=\underbrace{\int^{1}_{0}\ldots\int^{1}_{0}}_{\nu}\frac{(1-u_1^a\ldots u_{\nu}^a) \log u_1\ldots\log u_{\nu}du_1\ldots du_{\nu}}{(1-u_1\ldots u_{\nu})(1-u_1)\ldots (1-u_{\nu})}.
$$
Hence
$$
\underbrace{\int^{1}_{0}\ldots\int^{1}_{0}}_{\nu}\frac{(u_1^a\ldots u_{\nu}^a) \log u_1\ldots\log u_{\nu}du_1\ldots du_{\nu}}{(1-u_1\ldots u_{\nu})(1-u_1)\ldots (1-u_{\nu})}=
$$
$$
=C_{\nu}+(-1)^{\nu-1}\sum^{a-1}_{k=0}Z(2,k+1)(\psi'(k+1))^{\nu-1}
$$
And finaly
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\left(\psi'(k+a)\right)^{\nu}=C_{\nu}+(-1)^{\nu-1}\sum^{a-1}_{k=0}Z(2,k+1)(\psi'(k+1))^{\nu-1}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution! (+1) I think an interesting case would be a formula for $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\left(\psi'(k+a)\right)^{2} $ where $a$ could be *any positive real number*.