# On a trigamma squared series $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \psi^{(1)}(n) \right )^2}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions

Consider the series

$$\mathcal{S} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \psi^{(1)}(n) \right )^2}{n^2}$$

One way to evaluate it is by invoking the identity $\displaystyle \zeta(2) - \mathcal{H}_{n-1}^{(2)} = \psi^{(1)}(n)$ where $\mathcal{H}_{n}^{(2)}$ is the harmonic number of order $2$. Invoke some Euler sum identities and voila .

However, in this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882621/polygamma-function-series-displaystyle-sum-k-1-infty-left-psi1k) we have seen the evaluation of the series $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( \psi^{(1)}(n) \right )^2$. I wonder if we can use the same technique used in that link to tackle this series. This is the main question.

**Background:** This particular series arose while trying to evaluate the polygamma series

$$\mathcal{S} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi^{(1)}(n) \psi^{(1)} (n+1)}{n^2} $$

I managed to solve the latter series by not using this one but nevertheless it's quite interesting of its own. If anyone is interested the series evaluates to $\frac{9 \zeta(6)}{8}$.

Comment: The sum was discussed [here in I&S](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/integralsandseries/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=681&p=3882#p3882)

Comment: Thanks @r9m but I am asking if the technique applied by robjohn applies here as well.. ...

Comment: I am bumping this !