# Prove that $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^2x}{x-1}dx=\frac{\pi^4}{180}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, harmonic-numbers

Prove that (**please**)

> $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^2x}{x-1}dx=\frac{\pi^4}{180}$$

I've tried using Taylor series and I ended up with
$$-\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n(m+n+1)^3}$$
I am stuck there and I couldn't continue it using partial fraction to get any familiar sum of series. Could anyone here please help me to prove the integral preferably (**if possible**) with elementary ways (high school methods)? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think harmonic-numbers tag should be tagged as its very related to logarithmic integrals.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x - 1}\,\dd x
     ={\pi^{4} \over 180}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x - 1}\,\dd x
> =-\lim_{\mu \to -1\,\,\,\,\atop \nu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\partiald[2]{}{\nu}
> \int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x}^{\mu}x^{\nu}\,\dd x
> \\[5mm]&=-\lim_{\mu \to - 1\,\,\,\,\atop \nu \to 0}
> \partiald{}{\mu}\partiald[2]{}{\nu}{\rm B}\pars{\mu + 1,\nu + 1}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{{\rm B}\pars{x,y}}$ is the [Beta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html). Use expressions $\pars{23}$, $\pars{24}$, $\pars{25}$ and $\pars{26}$ from the above cited link.

Answer (score 9):

The idea is to use the fact that $\dfrac{\ln(1-x)}{x-1} = \sum\limits_{n \geq 1} H_n x^n$ where $|x| < 1$ and $H_n$ is the $n$'th harmonic number. This reduces the integral to a linear combination of $\sum\limits_{n \geq 1} H_n/n^3$ and $\sum\limits_{n \geq 1} 1/n^4$. The latter term is $\zeta(4) = \pi^4/90$; the former term is more difficult to calculate, but can be calculated with residues as well; a proof can be found here [here](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Unendliche_Reihen:_Reihen_mit_harmonischen_Zahlen). 
It seems very difficult to do this using only elementary methods.

More explicitly:

$$
I = \int_0^1\frac {\log(1 - u)}{u - 1}\, (\log u)^2 \, du = \int_0^1 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty H_n u^n \, (\log u)^2 \, du
= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty H_n \int_0^1 u^n\, (\log u)^2\, du = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty H_n\, \frac {2}{(n + 1)^3} = 2\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {H_{n - 1}}{n^3}
= 2\left(\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {H_n}{n^3} - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {1}{n^4}\right) = 2\left(\frac54\zeta(4) - \zeta(4)\right) = \frac{\pi^4}{180}.$$
Here we used the fact that $\int_0^{1}dx\, x^n \ln^2 x = \int_0^{\infty} dx\, e^{-(n+1)x} x^2 = \frac{2!}{(n+1)^3}$.
The penultimate equality is not so trivial to show (but see the comment by Tunk-Fey), but a proof is given in the link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link but I'd be grateful if you elaborate your answer regardless the method you use (elementary or sophisticated way.) +1 anyway ٩(^ᴗ^)۶

Comment: @V-Moy Here is the proof without using residue method:
$$
H_n=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+n}\right)=
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{n}{m(m+n)}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}=\sum_{m,n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^2m(n+m)}
=\sum_{m,n\geq1}\frac{1}{m^2n(n+m)}.
$$
Taking the half of sum we obtain
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m,n\geq1}\frac{1}{mn(m+n)}\left(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m,n\geq1}\frac{1}{m^2n^2}=\frac{1}{2}\zeta^2(2)
=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)^2
=\frac{\pi^4}{72}.$$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Very nice, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
-\int^1_0\frac{\ln^2{x}\ln(1-x)}{1-x}dx
&=-\int^1_0\frac{\ln{x}\ln(1-x)\ln(1-x)}{x}dx\tag1\\
&=\int^1_0\frac{\ln{x} \ \mathrm{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}dx-\int^1_0\underbrace{\frac{\ln(1-x) \ \mathrm{Li}_2(x)}{x}}_{-\mathrm{Li}_2(x)\mathrm{Li}_2'(x)}dx\tag2\\
&=-\frac{\pi^4}{120}+\frac{\pi^4}{72}\tag3\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{180}
\end{align}
Explanation: 
$(1)$ Substitute $x \mapsto 1-x$ 
$(2)$ Integrate by parts, with $u=\ln{x}\ln(1-x)$ and $v=\mathrm{Li}_2(x)$ 
$(3)$ The first integral is cleverly solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893618/integral-int1-0-frac-lnx-mathrmli-2x1-xdx) (I take absolutely no credit for it). For the second, observe that
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\mathrm{Li}_2(x)\mathrm{Li}_2'(x)dx
&=\left[\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Li}_2(x)^2\right]^1_0\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by user111187 is the cleanest way to approach such problem. I will elaborate on the sums (which he doesnt show).

$$I = (-)\cdot\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(1-x)\log^2(x) dx}{1-x}$$

Let $u = 1-x \implies du = -dx$

$$I = -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(u)\log^2(1-u) du}{u}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n u^n = -\frac{\log(1-u)}{1-u}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_nu^{n+1}}{n+1} = \frac{\log^2(1-u)}{2}$$

$$(2)\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n\log(u)\cdot u^{n}}{n+1} = \frac{\log^2(1-u)\log(u)}{u}$$

$$(-2)\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n+1}\cdot \int_{0}^{1} \log(u) \cdot u^{n} du = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log^2(1-u)\log(u)}{u} du = I$$

For the integral in the LHS, we simply use Leibniz's rule considering $\displaystyle J(n) = \int_{0}^{1} u^n du$ then differentiate.

$$(2)\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{(n+1)^3} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log^2(1-u)\log(u)}{u} du = I$$

$$H_n = H_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n} \implies H_{n+1} = H_{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} \implies H_n = H_{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}$$

$$ = (2)\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n+1}}{(n+1)^3} - (2)\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)^4}$$

$$ = (2)\cdot \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{n^3} - (2)\cdot\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n^4}$$

$$ = (2)\cdot \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{n^3} - 1   \right) - (2) \cdot \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n^4} - 1 \right)$$

From [Generalised Euler Sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469023/generalized-euler-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nnq)

$$ = (2)\cdot \left( \left(1 + \frac{3}{2} \right)\zeta(4) - \frac{1}{2}\zeta^2(2) - 1   \right) - 2\zeta(4) + 2$$

$$ = 5\zeta(4) - \zeta^2(2) - 2 - 2\zeta(4) + 2 = 3\zeta(4) - \zeta^2(2) = \frac{\pi^4}{180}$$

**Finally,**

$$I =  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(1-x)\log^2(x) \space dx}{x-1}  = \frac{\pi^4}{180}$$

Answer (score 1):

First, compute the series for $\log^2(1-x)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\log^2(1-x)
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}k\right)^2\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{k(n-k)}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^n}n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac1k+\frac1{n-k}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac2nH_{n-1}x^n\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
-\int_0^1\log(x)x^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\frac1n\int_0^1\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x^n\\
&=\frac1n\int_0^1x^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{n^2}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)\log^2(x)}{x-1}\mathrm{d}x
&=-\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}x\log^2(1-x)\mathrm{d}x\tag3\\
&=-\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac2nH_{n-1}\int_0^1\log(x)x^{n-1}\mathrm{d}x\tag4\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n^3}\tag5\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\color{#C00}{\frac{H_n}{n^3}}-\color{#090}{\frac1{n^4}}\right)\tag6\\
&=2\left(\color{#C00}{\frac52\zeta(4)-\frac12\zeta(2)^2}-\color{#090}{\zeta(4)}\right)\tag7\\[9pt]
&=3\zeta(4)-\zeta(2)^2\tag8\\[9pt]
&=\frac{\pi^4}{180}\tag9
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(3)$: substitute $x\mapsto1-x$
$(4)$: apply $(1)$
$(5)$: apply $(2)$ and $H_0=0$
$(6)$: $H_n=H_{n-1}+\frac1n$
$(7)$: apply [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/469785)
$(8)$: simplify
$(9)$: evaluate

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using Beta function:

We have [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402183/calculating-logarithmic-integrals-without-using-the-derivatives-of-beta-function)

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^{n}\ln^m(x)\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx=\frac12\frac{\partial^m}{\partial n^m}\left(H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}\right)$$

Set $m=2$ then let $n$ approach $0$ we get

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x\ln(1-x)}{1-x}dx=\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial n^2}\left(H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}\right)_{n\to 0}\\=\frac12\left(4H_nH_n^{(3)}+2\left(H_n^{(2)}\right)^2+6H_n^{(4)}-4\zeta(2)H_n^{(2)}-4\zeta(3)H_n-\zeta(4)\right)_{n\to 0}\\=-\frac12\zeta(4)$$