# Calculating logarithmic integrals without using the derivatives of Beta function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

How to prove the following generalizations  without using the derivatives of beta function:

> $$i)\int_0^1\frac{x^{n}\ln^m(x)\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx=(-1)^{m-1}m!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k}{(k+n+1)^{m+1}}\\=\frac12\frac{\partial^m}{\partial n^m}\left(H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}\right),\quad n>-2,\quad m\in\mathbb{N}$$

---

> $$ii)\int_0^1\frac{x^n\ln^m(x)\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx=(-1)^mm!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^2-H_k^{(2)}}{(k+n+1)^{m+1}}\\=-\frac1{3}\frac{\partial^m}{\partial n^m}\left(H_n^3+3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right),\quad n>-2,\quad m\in\mathbb{N}$$

---

The common problem with the derivative of Beta function $\text{B}(a,b)$ is the case when $a$ or $b$ approaches zero because we know that Beta derivative involves $\psi(a),\psi_1(a),\psi_2(a) ..$ and $\psi(b),\psi_1(b),\psi_2(b)...$ and the limit of these polygamma is undefined when $a$ or $b$ approaches zero and we will need the help of *Wolfram* or *Mathematica* to calculate such derivatives.

Using the above identities will help us avoid this issue as we just need to take the derivative of the harmonic number $\frac{\partial}{\partial n}H_n^{(a)}=a(\zeta(a+1)-H_n^{(a+1)})$ or you can simply convert the harmonic number to polygamma function $\psi_a(n+1)=(-1)^{a+1}a!(\zeta(a+1)-H_n^{(a+1)})$ as the derivative of polygamma is more straightforward.

---

I will provide the proofs soon but variant approaches are always appreciated.

Comment: Just a nitpick, the parameter $m$ needs to be greater than zero for the integrals to converge.

Comment: thank you .. I didnt test this case.

Answer (score 6):

**The first identity**:

From $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty H_kx^k=-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1-x}$$

It follows that

$$\small{\int_0^1\frac{x^{n}\ln^m(x)\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty H_k\int_0^1x^{n+k}\ln^m(x)\ dx=-(-1)^m m!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k}{(n+k+1)^{m+1}}}\tag1$$

By [the master theorem](http://files.ele-math.com/articles/jca-10-10.pdf) we have

$$\frac{H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}}{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k}{(k+1)(k+n+1)}\tag2$$

multiply both sides of $(2)$ by $n$ then differentiate with respect to $n$ we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k}{(n+k+1)^2}=\frac12\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\left(H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}\right)\tag3$$

Now if we differentiate both sides of $(3)$ with respect to $n$ $m$ times we get

$$-(-1)^m m! \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k}{(n+k+1)^{m+1}}=\frac12\frac{\partial^m}{\partial n^m}\left(H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}\right)\tag4$$
Plug $(4)$ in $(1)$ we get the first identity.

---

**The second identity:**

From [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366039/a-group-of-important-generating-functions-involving-harmonic-number)

$$\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (H_k^2-H_k^{(2)})x^k$$

it follows that

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^n\ln^m(x)\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx=(-1)^mm!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^2-H_k^{(2)}}{(k+n+1)^{m+1}}\tag1$$

Again, by the master theorem we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k^2-H_k^{(2)}}{(k+1)(k+n+1)}=\frac{H_n^3+3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}}{3n}\tag2$$

Multiply both sides of $(2)$ by $n$ then differentiate with respect to $n$ to have

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k^2-H_k^{(2)}}{(k+n+1)^2}=\frac13\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\left(H_n^3+3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right)\tag3$$

Now differentiate both sides of $(3)$ with respect to $n$ $m$ times we get

$$-(-1)^mm!\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k^2-H_k^{(2)}}{(k+n+1)^{m+1}}=\frac13\frac{\partial^m}{\partial n^m}\left(H_n^3+3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right)\tag4$$

Plug $(4)$ in $(1)$ we get the second identity

---

Full credit goes to Cornel as I just generalized [his solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3377671) to get the second identity. As for proving the first identity, I just followed the same approach.

---

**BONUS:**

Similarly, from [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366039/a-group-of-important-generating-functions-involving-harmonic-number)

$$-\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^3-3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right)x^n\tag1$$

It follows that

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^n\ln^m(x)\ln^3(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx=-(-1)^mm!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^3-3H_k H_k^{(2)}+2H_k^{(3)}}{(k+n+1)^{m+1}}\tag2$$

By the master theorem, we have

$$\small{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^3-3H_k H_k^{(2)}+2H_k^{(3)}}{(n+1)(k+n+1)}=\frac1{4n}\left(H_n^4+6H_n^2H_n^{(2)}+8H_nH_n^{(3)}+3\left(H_n^{(2)}\right)^2+6H_n^{(4)}\right)}\tag3$$

Multiply both sides of $(3)$ by $n$ then differentiate with respect to $n$ we get

$$\small{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^3-3H_k H_k^{(2)}+2H_k^{(3)}}{(k+n+1)^2}=\frac1{4}\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\left(H_n^4+6H_n^2H_n^{(2)}+8H_nH_n^{(3)}+3\left(H_n^{(2)}\right)^2+6H_n^{(4)}\right)}\tag4$$

Differentiate both sides of $(4)$ with respect to $n$ $m$ times we get

$$-(-1)^mm!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^3-3H_k H_k^{(2)}+2H_k^{(3)}}{(k+n+1)^{m+1}}\\=\frac1{4}\frac{\partial^m}{\partial n^m}\left(H_n^4+6H_n^2H_n^{(2)}+8H_nH_n^{(3)}+3\left(H_n^{(2)}\right)^2+6H_n^{(4)}\right)\tag5$$

Plug $(5)$ in $(2)$ we get

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^n\ln^m(x)\ln^3(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx=-(-1)^mm!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^3-3H_k H_k^{(2)}+2H_k^{(3)}}{(k+n+1)^{m+1}}\\=\frac1{4}\frac{\partial^m}{\partial n^m}\left(H_n^4+6H_n^2H_n^{(2)}+8H_nH_n^{(3)}+3\left(H_n^{(2)}\right)^2+6H_n^{(4)}\right)$$