# Integrals of the type $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^3 \ln^{2}(\sin x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, logarithms

> What approaches can be used for finding the following type of integrals:
>   $$\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {{x^3}\,{\ln }^2\left( {\sin x} \right)dx} \ \text{ or }\ \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x^3\ln^2(\cos x)dx \ ?$$

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04723.pdf) about *Generalized log-sine integrals and Bell polynomials* by *Derek Orr* is presented a popular approach to it, which consists of considering the following integral:
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x^n \sin^{2m} x\,dx$$
And derivating under the integral sign with respect to $m$ several times (see from page $8$).

Some results which yields using the above are:
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x\ln^2(\sin x)dx=\frac18\left(\frac{11\pi^4}{360}+\pi^2\ln^2 2-7\zeta(3)\ln 2+4\zeta(\bar 3,1)\right)$$
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x^3\ln^2(\sin x)dx$$$$=\frac{1}{64}\left(\frac{23\pi^6}{420}+\pi^4\ln^2 2+24\pi^2 \zeta(\bar 3,1)-48\zeta(\bar 5,1)-24\zeta^2(3)-18\pi^2\zeta(3)\ln 2+93\zeta(5)\ln 2\right)$$

Are there other ways to solve those integrals?

Comment: Do you mind posting what you have tried in solving these integrals? Thanks

Comment: @xuce1234 Are you interested to see a closed form for the sum of these two integrals?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Result:**

For your first integral, I obtained the following simplification:
\begin{align}\color{#FF4F00}{\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0x^3\ln^2(\sin{x})\ {\rm d}x=-\frac{187\pi^6}{26880}-\frac{3}{4}\zeta(\bar{5},1)+\frac{93}{64}\zeta(5)\ln{2}+\frac{3\pi^2}{4}{\rm Li}_4\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi^4}{64}\ln^2{2}-\frac{3}{8}\zeta^2(3)+\frac{3\pi^2}{8}\zeta(3)\ln{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{32}\ln^4{2}}\end{align}

---

**Derivation:**

I will start off with the evaluation of $\displaystyle\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0x^3\ln(\sin{x})\ {\rm d}x$.
\begin{align}
\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0x^3\ln(\sin{x})\ {\rm d}x
&=-\ln{2}\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0x^3\ {\rm d}x-\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n}\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0x^3\cos(2nx)\ {\rm d}x\tag1\\
&=-\frac{\pi^4}{64}\ln{2}+\frac{3\pi^2}{16}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^3}-\frac{3}{8}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\left[1+(-1)^{n-1}\right]}{n^5}\tag2\\
&=-\frac{\pi^4}{64}\ln{2}+\frac{9\pi^2}{64}\zeta(3)-\frac{93}{128}\zeta(5)\tag3\\
\end{align}
Note that
$$\ln^2(\sin{x})={\rm Re}\ln^2(1-e^{i2x})-2\ln{2}\ln(\sin{x})+\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2-\ln^2{2}\tag4$$
Using this identity on the first integral,
\begin{align}
&\small{\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0x^3\ln^2(\sin{x})\ {\rm d}x}\\
=&\small{{\rm Re}\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0x^3\ln^2(1-e^{i2x})\ {\rm d}x+\underbrace{\frac{\pi^6}{3840}+\frac{93}{64}\zeta(5)\ln{2}+\frac{\pi^4}{64}\ln^2{2}-\frac{9\pi^2}{32}\zeta(3)\ln{2}}_{\text{Let this be $\mathcal{K}$}}}\tag5\\
=&\small{\frac{1}{16}{\rm Re}\int^{-1}_1\frac{\ln^3{z}\ln^2(1-z)}{z}{\rm d}z+\mathcal{K}}\tag6\\
=&\small{\frac{1}{16}\underbrace{\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3{z}\ln^2(1+z)}{z}{\rm d}z}_{\mathcal{I}_1}-\frac{3\pi^2}{16}\underbrace{\int^1_0\frac{\ln{z}\ln^2(1+z)}{z}{\rm d}z}_{\mathcal{I}_2}-\frac{1}{16}\underbrace{\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3{z}\ln^2(1-z)}{z}{\rm d}z}_{\mathcal{I}_3}+\mathcal{K}\tag7}
\end{align}
I am unable to find a closed form for $\mathcal{I}_1$ (I doubt there is one but feel free to prove me wrong), so I have no choice but to express it as a multiple zeta value.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}_1
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0\frac{\ln^4{z}\ln(1+z)}{1+z}{\rm d}z\tag8\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}H_n\int^1_0z^n\ln^4{z}\ {\rm d}z\tag9\\
&=-12\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_n}{(n+1)^5}\\
&=-12\zeta(\bar{5},1)
\end{align}
$\mathcal{I}_2$ can be handled, but its evaluation is very lengthy so I will simply use a previous result derived from another post.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}_2
&=-\int^1_0\frac{\ln^2{z}\ln(1+z)}{1+z}{\rm d}z\tag{10}\\
&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^{n}H_n\int^1_0z^n\ln^2{z}\ {\rm d}z\tag{11}\\
&=2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_n}{n^3}-2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^4}\\
&=-4{\rm Li}_4\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi^4}{24}-\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)\ln{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\ln^2{2}-\frac{1}{6}\ln^4{2}\tag{12}\\
\end{align}
$\mathcal{I}_3$ is the easiest of the three integrals.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}_3
&=\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0\frac{\ln^4{z}\ln(1-z)}{1-z}{\rm d}z\tag{13}\\
&=-12\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{(n+1)^5}\tag{14}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^6}{105}+6\zeta^2(3)\tag{15}\\
\end{align}
Combining these results, we obtain
\begin{align}\color{#FF4F00}{\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0x^3\ln^2(\sin{x})\ {\rm d}x=-\frac{187\pi^6}{26880}-\frac{3}{4}\zeta(\bar{5},1)+\frac{93}{64}\zeta(5)\ln{2}+\frac{3\pi^2}{4}{\rm Li}_4\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi^4}{64}\ln^2{2}-\frac{3}{8}\zeta^2(3)+\frac{3\pi^2}{8}\zeta(3)\ln{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{32}\ln^4{2}}\end{align}
A similar methodology can be used to simplify your other integral. Note that this isn't exactly a closed form due to the multiple zeta value.

---

**Explanation:**

$(1): \text{Use the Fourier series expansion of $\ln(\sin{x})$.}$

$(2): \text{Integrate by parts.}$

$(5): \text{Apply $(3)$ and $(4)$.}$

$(6): \text{Let $z=e^{i2x}$.}$

$(7): \text{Extract the real part.}$

$(8): \text{Integrate by parts.}$

$(9): \text{Expand using the generating function of $H_n$.}$

$(10): \text{Integrate by parts.}$

$(11): \text{Expand using the generating function of $H_n$.}$

$(12): \text{See}$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457371/alternating-harmonic-sum-sum-k-geq-1-frac-1kk3h-k?lq=1). 

$(13): \text{Integrate by parts.}$

$(14): \text{Expand using the generating function of $H_n$.}$

$(15): \text{See}$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469023/generalized-euler-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nnq).

Comment: You always have good answers for the recent integral problems in MSE. I learn a lot through your posts. Thanks. +1

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova I appreciate your compliment. Thanks.