# Generalized series involving harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

I was wondering whether is possible to find a closed form for the series $$\Xi(s)=\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{H_n}{n^s}$$ with $s\in(1,\infty)$ to let the series converge, or, at least with $s\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$. Since $\Xi(2)=2\zeta(3)$ and $\Xi(3)=\frac{\zeta^2(2)}2$, I suppose $\Xi(s\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\})$ can all be expressed in terms of Riemann $\zeta(z)$ function. The problem is that, while for $s=2$ we work with $\mathrm{Li}_2(x)$ and for $s=3$ it's all about reindexing, using these methods for $s\geq4$ becomes quite difficult. I'm sure I lack of some polylog's important identities, so I ask for your help: have you some idea to deduce a closed form of $\Xi(s)$?

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function) for even a more general case (you may also want to follow links out there).

Comment: Check this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469023/generalized-euler-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nnq