# Double infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Compute the infinite sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{n+k+1}{nk(n+k)^2}$$. I calculated the first part and got $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+k+1}{nk(n+k)^2}=\sum_{j=0}^{j=n}\frac{1}{n^2j}+\sum_{j=0}^{j=n}\frac{1}{n^3}{j}+\sum_{j=0}^{j=n}+\frac{1}{n^2j^2}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$$. But don't know how to proceed.

Comment: The expression under the double sum makes no sense for $k=0$. Please adjust. Also, would you please add more context to the question - which is the source, e.g. author, year, level, country, etc. is it from a book, a test, a contest... ?!

Comment: Do you mind spelling out your steps? For me it's not obvious how you got your result.
And is the $+$ behind the second-to-last $Σ$ intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+k+1}{nk(n+k)^2}=\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{nk(n+k)}}_{I}+\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{nk(n+k)^2}}_{J}
$$
,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n k}\int_0^{{\infty}}e^{-(n+k)t}dt
\\&=\int_0^{{\infty}} \ln^2(1-e^{-t})dt
\\&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx
\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^1 x^n \ln^2 x dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(n+1)^3}
\\&=2\zeta(3)
\end{aligned}
$$
Similarly,
$$
J=\int_0^1 t \ln^2(1-e^{-t})=-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x \ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx
$$
From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3801019/903232),we know
$$
J=\frac{\pi ^4}{180}
$$
Combine the results above,we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+k+1}{nk(n+k)^2}=2 \zeta (3)+\frac{\pi ^4}{180}
$$