# What is $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin x)}\:\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: definite-integrals

Could you prove that: 
\begin{align} \displaystyle 2\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin x)}\:\mathrm{d}x\right)^{7} + & 53 \left(\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin x)}\:\mathrm{d}x\right)^{5} \\ + \left(\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin x)}\:\mathrm{d}x\right)^{4} + & \quad \left(\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin x)}\:\mathrm{d}x\right)^{3} \\ + & 19\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin x)}\:\mathrm{d}x = 2014 \end{align}
Just for the fun of it.

Observe that $2\times53\times1\times1\times19=2014.$

EDIT: A different proof of
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin x)}\:\mathrm{d}x = 2
$$
may be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878698/integral-int-0-pi-fracxx2-ln22-sin-x-dx/878710#878710). Thanks.

Comment: The integral evaluates to $2$, so what you have is $2\cdot 2^7+53\cdot 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 19\cdot 2 = 2014$. As for how to evaluate the integral, I would probably employ a complex analytic technique to do it.

Comment: @Cameron Williams, Well done!

Comment: Before, we have to prove that the integral is equal to $\large 2$ since $\large 2^{8} + 53\times 2^{5} + 2^{4} + 2^{3} + 19\times 2 = 2014$.

Comment: Yes, the question is to prove that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin x)}\:\mathrm{d}x = 2.$

Comment: you're right, thanks!

Comment: The numerical integration leads to 2; would any one be able to prove it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I will provide a proof if nobody finds one.

Comment: @OlivierOloa. I really wait for that ! Cheers.

Comment: Not sure this is relevant: $$x^2+\log^2{(2 \sin{x})} = \left | \log{\left [ i \left ( 1-e^{i 2 x}\right ) \right ]}\right |^2$$

Comment: @RonGordon, yes it is.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large =\Re\int_{0}^{\pi}{{\rm d}x \over x - {\rm i}\ \ln\left(2\sin\left(x\right)\right)}}$

Comment: I believe this may be useful: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(n y)\,e^{-my} dy = \frac{n}{n^2+m^2}$$

Comment: You can find a solution [here](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic301.html#p1978).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a proof, using complex analysis, that the integral is equal to $2$. Put
$$
f(z) = {1\over\log{(i(1-e^{i2z}))}},
$$
the logarithm being the principal branch. As can be deduced from the comments, the original integral is equal to
$$
\int_0^\pi \operatorname{Re}{f(x)}\,dx.
$$
Next consider, for $R>\epsilon > 0$, the following contour:

[image]

It is straightforward to check that for each fixed $\epsilon$ and $R$, the function $f$ is analytic on an open set containing this contour (just consider where $i(1-e^{i2z})\leq0$; this can only happen when $\operatorname{Im}{z}<0$ or when $\operatorname{Im}{z} = 0$ and $\operatorname{Re}{z}$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$). It then follows from Cauchy's theorem that $f$ integrates to zero over it. First let's see that the integrals over the quarter-circular portions of the contour vanish in the limit $\epsilon \to 0$. I'll look at the quarter circle near $\pi$ (near the bottom right corner of the contour) but the one near zero is similar, if not easier. Writing $i(1-e^{i2z}) = i(1-e^{i2(z-\pi)})$, it is clear that $i(1-e^{i2z}) = O(z-\pi)$ as $z\to\pi$. It follows from this that $f(z) = O(1/\log{|z-\pi|})$ as $z\to0$, and therefore that the integral of $f$ over the bottom right quarter circle is $O(\epsilon/\log{\epsilon})$ as $\epsilon \to0$, hence it vanishes in the limit as claimed.

Thus for fixed $R$, we can let $\epsilon \to 0$ to see that $f$ integrates to zero over the rectangle with corners $0,\pi, \pi +iR,$ and $iR$. Now the vertical sides of this rectangle give the contribution
\begin{align*}
-\int_0^R f(iy)\,idy + \int_0^R f(iy+\pi)\,idy = 0,
\end{align*}
since $f(iy) = f(iy+\pi)$. It follows at once that for each $R$, we can set the contribution from the horizontal sides equal to zero, giving
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi} f(x)\,dx - \int_0^\pi f(x+iR)\,dx=0, \qquad R>0. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
(Note that the above equation implies that the integral in $x$ of $f(x+iR)$ over the interval $[0,\pi]$ is constant as a function of $R$; another way to evaluate the integral is to prove this directly, which I'll add below in a moment.) Now $f(x+iR) \to 1/\log{i} = 2/\pi$ as $R\to\infty$, uniformly for $x\in[0,\pi]$. Thus
\begin{align*}
\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_0^\pi f(x+iR)\,dx = \pi\cdot {2\over \pi} = 2,
\end{align*}
and it follows from $(1)$ that the original integral is equal to $2$ as well.

(By the way, the above idea is basically a replication of the technique I used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58654/integrate-square-of-the-log-sine-integral-int-0-frac-pi2-ln2-sinx/119877#119877) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119253/interesting-square-of-log-sin-integral/126470#126470), and which I originally got from Ahlfors' book on complex analysis.)

Comment: amazing answer (+1)!

Comment: Bravo! (+1) $   $

Comment: Thanks all! And I like your solution too @IntegralsandSeries

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi}{x \over x^{2} + \ln^{2}\pars{2\sin\pars{x}}}\,\dd x = 2:
     \ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{0}^{\pi}{x \over x^{2} + \ln^{2}\pars{2\sin\pars{x}}}\,\dd x}
> =-\,\Im\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd x \over x\ic + \ln\pars{2\sin\pars{x}}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\Im
> \int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1\atop{\vphantom{\Huge A}0\ <\ {\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ <\ \pi}}
> {\dd z/\pars{\ic z}\over
> \ln\pars{z} + \ln\pars{2\bracks{z^{2} - 1}/\bracks{2\ic z}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\Re
> \int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1\atop{\vphantom{\Huge A}0\ <\ {\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ <\ \pi}}
> {1 \over \ln\pars{\bracks{1 - z^{2}}\ic}}\,{\dd z \over z}
> \end{align}

We close the contour with the 'line segment'
$\ds{\braces{\pars{x,0}\ \mid\ x \in \pars{-1,1}}}$ with 'indented points' at $\ds{z = -1,0,1}$. I t turns out that the whole contribution to the integral arises from the 'indented point' at $\ds{z = 0}$: See my [detailed calculation in one of  my previous answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/881826/85343) which is very close to the present one. Then,

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{0}^{\pi}{x \over x^{2} + \ln^{2}\pars{2\sin\pars{x}}}\,\dd x}
> =\left. -\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}\Re\int_{\pi}^{0}
> {1 \over \ln\pars{\bracks{1 - z^{2}}\ic}}\,{\dd z \over z}
> \right\vert_{\,z\ \equiv\ \epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\Re\int_{\pi}^{0}{1 \over \ln\pars{\ic}}\,\ic\,\dd\theta
> =-\,\Re\int_{\pi}^{0}{1 \over \pi\,\ic/2}\,\ic\,\dd\theta
> =-\,{2 \over \pi}\int_{\pi}^{0}\dd\theta
> =\color{#66f}{\Large 2}
> \end{align}