# parameter value in the solution of $\int_0^\pi\arctan\bigl(\frac{\ln\alpha\sin x}{x}\bigr)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

[Evaluating $\int_0^\pi\arctan\bigl(\frac{\ln\sin x}{x}\bigr)\mathrm{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878341/evaluating-int-0-pi-arctan-bigl-frac-ln-sin-xx-bigr-mathrmdx)

In the first two solutions of the above post,why is the parameter value $\alpha\in(0,1)$ or $\mu\in(0,1)$ . The solution does seem to work for $\alpha\geqslant 1$ or $\mu\geqslant 1$ also.

Answer (score 3):

In the linked post, the **first** answer by @M.N.C.E. gave the answer.

Using your notation and his/her result
$$I'(\alpha)=\frac {\pi^2}{2\alpha} \frac{1}{\log ^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi ^2}{4}}$$ and
$$\int_0^\pi \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\log (\alpha \sin (x))}{x}\right)\,dx=\pi  \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 }{\pi }\log \left(\frac{\alpha
   }{2}\right)\right)$$ which works $\forall \alpha >0$.

Comment: But i am not able to understand why @CuriousGuest & Felix Marin both assume the parameter to be in the range (0,1)?