# Integral: $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin x)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I am trying to solve the following by **elementary** methods:
$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin x)}\,dx$$

---

I wrote the integral as:
$$\Re\int_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{x-i\ln(2\sin x)}$$
But I don't find this easier than the original integral. I have seen solutions which make use of complex analysis but I am interested in elementary approaches.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know, even using non elementary methods but the beautiful thing is that your last integral is a real ! +1 for this interesting question. Cheers.

Comment: Beats me why there's a downvote, but I upvoted because I've been wondering this too and I want a darn answer. Is the integral really exactly $2$??

Comment: Here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625456/what-is-int-0-pi-fracxx2-ln22-sin-x-mathrmdx

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is an approach without using contour integration (Cauchy's theorem).

I've found the following result.

> **Theorem.** Let $a$ be any real number.
>
> Then
>   $$
> \begin{align} 
>   \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2 e^{a} \sin x)}\mathrm{d}x 
>   & = \, \frac{2 \pi^2}{\pi^2+4a^2},\tag1\\\\ 
>   \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\ln(2 e^{a} \sin x)}{x^2+\ln^2(2 e^{a} \sin x)}\mathrm{d}x & =  \frac{4\pi a}{\pi^2+4a^2}.\tag2
> \end{align} 
> $$

from which, *by putting* $a=0$, you deduce the evaluation of the desired integral:

> Example $1 (a)$. $$ \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2 \sin x)}\:\mathrm{d}x 
>   & = 2 \tag3
> \end{align}
> $$

and

> Example $1 (b)$. $$ \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\ln(2\sin x)}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin x)}\mathrm{d}x& = 0. \\ \tag4
> \end{align}
> $$

*Proof of the Theorem.* We consider throughout the principal value of $\log(z)$ defined for $z\neq 0$ by
$$
\log(z)= \ln |z| + i \arg z, \,  - \pi < \arg z \leq \pi,
$$
where $\ln$ is the base-$e$ logarithm $\ln e = 1$.

Let $a$ be any real number. Since $\displaystyle z \mapsto i \pi/2+a+\log(1+z) $ is analytic on $|z| < 1$ non-vanishing at the point $z=0$, one may obtain the following power series expansion
$$
\begin{align} 
\displaystyle \frac{1}{i \pi/2+a+\log \left(1+z\right)} - \frac{1}{i \pi/2+a}
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \displaystyle \frac{a_n(\alpha)}{n!} z^n,\tag5
\end{align}
$$  with
$$  \displaystyle a_1(\alpha) = -\alpha^2,  
\quad a_2(\alpha) = \alpha^3+\alpha^2/2, \, ... ,
$$
$\displaystyle {a}_n(\cdot)$ being a polynomial of degree $n+1$ in  $\displaystyle \alpha$,
 where we have set $\displaystyle \alpha:=1/(i \pi/2+a)$. 
Plugging $z=-e^{2ix}$ in $(3)$, for $0<x<\pi$, 
noticing 
$$
i x +\ln(2e^{a} \sin x) = \log\left(ie^{a}\left(1-e^{2ix} \right) \right),
$$
separating real and imaginary parts, gives the Fourier series expansions:
$$
\begin{align} 
\displaystyle \frac{x}{x^2 +\ln^2(2e^{a}\sin x)}
 & =  \frac{2\pi}{\pi^2+4a^2}+  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \left( \frac{a_n^{-}(\alpha)}{n!} \cos (2nx)+\frac{a_n^{+}(\alpha)}{n!} \sin (2nx)\right)
\\ \frac{\ln(2e^{a}\sin x)}{x^2 +\ln^2(2e^{a}\sin x)}
 & =  \frac{4a}{\pi^2+4a^2}+  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \left( \frac{a_n^{+}(\alpha)}{n!} \cos (2nx)-\frac{a_n^{-}(\alpha)}{n!} \sin (2nx)\right)
\end{align}
$$ with $\displaystyle a_n^{+}(\alpha):= {\mathfrak{R}}a_n(\alpha)$ and $\displaystyle a_n^{-}(\alpha):= {\mathfrak{I}}a_n(\alpha)$.
Now, a termwise integration with respect to $x$ from 0 to $\pi$, justified by the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \displaystyle \frac{a_n(\alpha)}{n!}  $, leads to the Theorem due to 
$$
\begin{align} 
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(2nx)\:\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(2nx)\:\mathrm{d}x = 0.
\end{align}
$$

---

One may observe that, by uniqueness of the Fourier coefficients, you have the following closed forms.

> Example $2 (a)$.
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2 \sin x)}\cos^{2} x \:\mathrm{d}x 
>   & = 1,  \tag6 \\ 
>   \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2 \sin x)}\sin^{2} x\:\mathrm{d}x & =  1. \tag7
> \end{align} 
> $$

$$
$$

> Example $2 (b)$.
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>   \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\ln(2 \sin x)}{x^2+\ln^2(2 \sin x)} \cos^{2} x \:\mathrm{d}x 
>   & = -\frac{1}{\pi},  \tag8 \\ 
>   \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\ln(2 \sin x)}{x^2+\ln^2(2 \sin x)}\sin^{2} x\:\mathrm{d}x & = \frac{1}{\pi}. \tag9
> \end{align} 
> $$

A general result does exist.

Comment: Thank you Oliver Oloa for the response but I cannot understand most of it. :( What does the statement "Since $z↦\log(1+z)$ is analytic on $|z|<1$, one may obtain the following power series expansion" mean? And then, why did you introduce the subsequent series expansion? Can you please share some motivation behind introducing $e^a$? Sorry for too many dumb questions. Thank you again.

Comment: @PranavArora. There is no dumb question ! I am fascinated by this answer but I am almost sure I just understand a few percents of it. Cheers :)

Comment: @Oliver Oloa. Do you have many things like that ? By the way, where are you in Paris ? Cheers from Pau :)

Comment: @Pranav Arora When an analytic function $h$ say near $z_0=0$ is such that $h(0) \neq 0$, then the reciprocal $z \mapsto 1/h(z)$ is also analytic near $0$. We are in this case here. Thank you.

Comment: I do not know what an analytic function is. I think I will have to learn about that before trying to understanding your answer. Thank you for your time, I accept your answer. :)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Yes. I'm not in Paris intra muros. Thanks.

Comment: @Pranav Arora Thank you very much for your interest, and thanks to accept my answer now :)!

Comment: @Pranav Arora You should give a link, in your question, to the related post I made on the subject (January 2014). Thank you.