# Vardi's Integral: $\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \ln (\ln(\tan x))dx $

Tags: calculus

Prove that:

$\displaystyle\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \ln (\ln(\tan x))dx =\frac{\pi}{2}\ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{2\pi} \Gamma \left(\dfrac{3}{4} \right)}{\Gamma \left(\dfrac{1}{4} \right)}\right)$

I know that the Vardi's Integral can be evaluated in terms of derivatives of Hurwitz Zeta Function. I would like to see a method which uses differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: You seem to know very well what you want. Did you try anything in this direction?

Comment: Yes, I have evaluated it using Hurwitz Zeta Function but I want to know if there is an alternate approach.

Comment: Let $\tan x=1/t$ and check this out: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121545/evaluating-int-01-log-log-left-frac1x-right-fracdx1x2?rq=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm going to sketch a way to transform the integral into a sum.  The sum looks difficult, but it converges and numerically checks with the stated result.

Begin by substituting $u=\log{\tan{x}}$.  Then

$$du = \frac{1}{\tan{x}} \sec^2{x} \, dx = \left ( \frac{1}{\tan{x}} + \tan{x} \right ) dx = (e^{-u} + e^u) \, dx $$

and

$$\begin{align} \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} dx \: \ln (\ln(\tan x)) &= \int_0^{\infty} du \: \frac{\log{u}}{e^u + e^{-u}} \\ &= \int_0^{\infty} du \: \frac{e^{-u} \log{u}}{1+e^{-2 u}} \\ &= \int_0^{\infty} du \: e^{-u} \log{u} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k e^{-2 k u} \end{align}$$

Reverse the order of sum and integral, which is justified by Fubini's Theorem (both sum and integral are absolutely convergent).  Then we may write

$$\begin{align} \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} dx \: \ln (\ln(\tan x)) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \int_0^{\infty} du \:  e^{-(2 k+1) u} \log{u} \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2 k+1} \int_0^{\infty} du \:  e^{-u} \log{u} - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{\log{(2 k+1)}}{2 k+1} \int_0^{\infty} du \:  e^{-u}  \\ &= -\frac{\pi}{4} \gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{\log{(2 k+1)}}{2 k+1} \\ \end{align} $$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.  The sum on the right-hand sign [is known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Series_expansions):

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{\log{(2 k+1)}}{2 k+1} = \frac{\pi}{4} \gamma + \frac{\pi}{4} \log{\frac{\Gamma{\left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )}^4}{\pi}} $$

Use the [fact](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5) that

$$\Gamma{\left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )} \Gamma{\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )} = \sqrt{2} \pi$$

to deduce that

$$ \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} dx \: \ln (\ln(\tan x)) = \frac{\pi}{2} \log{\left [\sqrt{2 \pi} \frac{\Gamma{\left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )}}{\Gamma{\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )}}\right ]} $$

Comment: This is just great. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As a matter of fact, there is [a very nice paper by Iaroslav Blagouchine](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-013-9528-5) in which the *Vardi's integral*, as well as numerous integrals akin to it, are treated in details (more correctly they should be called *Malmsten's integrals*).

Answer (score -1):

$$
I := \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \log \log \tan x \,dx
$$

is, after substitution $x \mapsto \arctan e^{x}$, equal to

$$
\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log x}{\cosh x} \,dx.
$$

Further, this can be expressed as

$$
\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log \pi x}{\cosh \pi x} \,dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \log \sqrt{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\cosh \pi x} + \frac{\pi}{8} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log x^{2}}{\cosh \pi x} \,dx.
$$

Here, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\cosh \pi x} = 1$, and according to the formula

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log(\alpha^{2}+x^{2})}{\cosh \pi x} \,dx = 4 \log \left(\sqrt{2} \; \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4} + \frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\right)
$$

for $\alpha \geq 0$, it follows that

$$
\frac{\pi}{8} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log x^{2}}{\cosh \pi x} \,dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \log \left(\sqrt{2} \, \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\right).
$$

Therefore,

$$
I = \frac{\pi}{2} \log \left(\sqrt{2\pi} \; \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\right).
$$

Comment: Why downvote???

Answer (score -1):

In the formula

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log \log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+2\cos \alpha \pi \cdot x+x^{2}} \,dx = \frac{\pi}{2\sin \alpha \pi} \left(\alpha \log 2\pi + \log \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\right)$$

set $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log \log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+x^{2}} \,dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \left(\log \sqrt{2\pi} + \log \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\right)$$

Through the substitution $x\mapsto \cot x$, the aforementioned equation is obtained

Comment: Why downvote???