# Two log trig integral

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, fourier-series

$$\begin{align*}
  & \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{{{\ln }^{n}}\sin x\text{d}x} \\ 
 & \int_{\frac{\pi }{4}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\ln \left( \ln \tan x \right)}\text{d}x \\ 
\end{align*}$$

Comment: The $2$nd integral is called Vardi's integral and you may find here a solution: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285671/vardis-integral-int-pi-4-pi-2-ln-ln-tan-xdx. For the first integral I wonder if it helps to let $\ln\sin x = u$.

Comment: @Chris'ssister :Thx Chris : )

Comment: nice questions +1

Comment: @Chris'ssister: thanks for the link.

Comment: @rlgordonma: welcome :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first integral is the log-sine integral.  See this post to see how to evaluate it:
[Solve the integral $S_k = (-1)^k \int_0^1 (\log(\sin \pi x))^k dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121473/solve-the-integral-displaystyles-k-1k-int-01-log-sin-pi-xk-dx)