# Integral $ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln \ln (1/x)}{1+x^{2p}} dx$...Definite Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, contour-integration

Calculate
$$
I_1:=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \ln (1/x)}{1+x^{2p}} dx, \ p \geq 1.
$$
I am trying to solve this integral $I_1$.  I know how to solve a related integral $I_2$
$$
I_2:=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \ln (1/x)}{1+x^2} dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\bigg(2\ln 2 +3\ln \pi-4\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{4}\big) \bigg)
$$
but I am not sure how to use that result here. In this case I just use the substitution $x=e^{-\xi}$ and than use a series expansion.  The result is
$$
I_2=\int_0^\infty \frac{\xi^s e^{-\xi}}{1+e^{-2\xi}} d\xi=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{(2n+1)^{s+1}}=\Gamma(s+1)L(s+1,\chi_4)
$$
where L is the Dirichlet L-Function where $\chi_4$ is the unique non-principal character.  This result is further simplified but takes some work.  I am interested in the general case above, $I_1$ Thanks

Comment: I believe you made some typos in your subscripts.

Comment: There is something similar  
[over here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/121618/85343) .

Comment: @FelixMarin: There is *definitely* similar over there. :-)

Comment: I have
[an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/695637/85343) that can be helpful.

Comment: @FelixMarin As stated in the post, I have calculated that integral that you are saying looks similar.  It is $I_2$ in my post. Thanks anyways.  I need the general case as this is most important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1/x}} \over 1 + x^{2p}}\,\dd x\,,\qquad
     p \geq 1:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1/x}} \over 1 + x^{2p}}\,\dd x
> =\overbrace{\int_{\infty}^{1}{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{x}} \over 1 + x^{-2p}}
> \,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}}^{\ds{x\ \to\ {1 \over x}}}
> =\int_{1}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{x}}x^{-2} \over 1 + x^{-2p}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {\ln\pars{t}\expo{-2t} \over 1 + \expo{-2pt}}\,\expo{t}\,\dd t}
> _{\ds{x\ \equiv \expo{t}}}
> =\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\mu}\expo{-t}\,
> {1 \over 1 + \expo{-2pt}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\mu}\expo{-t}\,
> \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{\ell}\expo{-2\ell pt}\,\dd t
> =\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
> \pars{-1}^{\ell}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\mu}\expo{-\pars{2\ell p + 1}t}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
> {\pars{-1}^{\ell} \over \pars{2\ell p + 1}^{\mu + 1}}
> \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\mu}\expo{-t}\,\dd t}_{\ds{=\ \Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}}}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the
>   [Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

$$
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1/x}} \over 1 + x^{2p}}\,\dd x
=\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}%
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{\ell} \over \pars{2\ell p + 1}^{\mu + 1}}}
\tag{1}
$$

> Let's reduce the $\ds{\ell}$-sum in the right hand side:
>   \begin{align}
> &\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{\ell} \over \pars{2\ell p + 1}^{\mu + 1}}
> =\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\braces{%
> {1 \over \bracks{2\pars{2\ell}p + 1}^{\mu + 1}}-
> {1 \over \bracks{2\pars{2\ell + 1}p + 1}^{\mu + 1}}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \pars{4p}^{\mu + 1}}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\braces{%
> {1 \over \bracks{\ell + 1/\pars{4p}}^{\mu + 1}}-
> {1 \over \bracks{\ell + 1/2 + 1/\pars{4p}}^{\mu + 1}}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \pars{4p}^{\mu + 1}}\bracks{%
> \zeta\pars{\mu + 1,{1 \over 4p}} - \zeta\pars{\mu + 1,\half + {1 \over 4p}}}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\zeta\pars{s,q}}$ is the
>   [Generalizated Zeta Function or/and Hurwitz Zeta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function).

$\pars{1}$ is reduced to:
\begin{align}
&\!\!\!\!\!\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1/x}} \over 1 + x^{2p}}\,\dd x
=\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\braces{%
{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} \over \pars{4p}^{\mu + 1}}\bracks{%
\zeta\pars{\mu + 1,{1 \over 4p}} - \zeta\pars{\mu + 1,\half + {1 \over 4p}}}}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> Also ( [see this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) ):
>   \begin{align}
> &\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
> \zeta\pars{\nu + 1,{1 \over 4p}} - \zeta\pars{\nu + 1,\half + {1 \over 4p}}
> =
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n!}\,
> \bracks{\gamma_{n}\pars{1 \over 4p} - \gamma_{n}\pars{\half + {1 \over 4p}}}\nu^{n}
> \tag{3}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\gamma_{n}\pars{a}}$ is a
>   [Generalizated Stieltjes Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants).

With the expression $\pars{3}$, $\pars{2}$ is reduced to:
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1/x}} \over 1 + x^{2p}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n!}\,
\bracks{\gamma_{n}\pars{1 \over 4p} - \gamma_{n}\pars{\half + {1 \over 4p}}}\
\overbrace{\braces{\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{%
\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\mu^{n} \over \pars{4p}^{\mu + 1}}}}
^{\ds{-\bracks{\gamma + \ln\pars{4p}}\delta_{n,0} + \delta_{n,1} \over 4p}}
\\[3mm]&={\gamma + \ln\pars{4p} \over 4p}\,\bracks{%
\gamma_{0}\pars{\half + {1 \over 4p}} - \gamma_{0}\pars{1 \over 4p}}
+
{1 \over 4p}\,
\bracks{\gamma_{1}\pars{\half + {1 \over 4p}} - \gamma_{1}\pars{1 \over 4p}}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\gamma}$ is the
[Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant).

According to the [Blagouchine paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.3724v2.pdf):
$\ds{\gamma_{0}\pars{v} = -\Psi\pars{v}}$ where $\ds{\Psi\pars{v}}$ is the
[Digamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

> Finally, we arrive to this answer *main result*:
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1/x}} \over 1 + x^{2p}}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{{\gamma + \ln\pars{4p} \over 4p}\,\bracks{%
> \Psi\pars{1 \over 4p} - \Psi\pars{\half + {1 \over 4p}}}
> +
> {1 \over 4p}\,
> \bracks{\gamma_{1}\pars{\half + {1 \over 4p}} - \gamma_{1}\pars{1 \over 4p}}}
> \end{align}
>   The constants $\ds{\braces{\gamma_{1}\pars{a}}}$ can be calculated for rational values of $a$ by means of a rather cumbersome expression (see formula $\pars{26}$ in
>   [Blagouchine paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.3724v2.pdf) ). When $\ds{p = 1}$, the results is [somehow simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/695637/85343) since we can use formula $\pars{11}$ of
>   [Blagouchine paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.3724v2.pdf) which is valid when
>   $\ds{{1 \over 4p} + \pars{\half + {1 \over 4p}} = 1}$.

## ADDENDUM

Recently, the paper by Professor Blagouchine was published in *Journal of Number Theory* as he
told me via a comment. See the following link: 
[A theorem for the closed-form evaluation of the first generalized Stieltjes constant at rational arguments and some related summations](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X14002820) .

Comment: this is excellent.  I will work through it and let you know if I have further questions.  Very nice solution, thanks Alot!!

Comment: Wanted to add, the paper by Blagouchine looks very helpful as well!    Thanks

Comment: @Jeff That paper is, indeed, wonderful. It's quite fresh: Feb-2014. Thanks.

Comment: @Felix The preprint of my paper which You mentioned here was recently published by the Journal of Number Theory. [The journal version of the paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X14002820) is considerably enlarged and additionally contains numerous summation formulae with the first Stieltjes constant and the Digamma function, an integral representation for $\ln\Gamma(z)$ at rational $z$ and some interesting series for Euler's constant. If You, or someone else, is interested in this journal version, I can send it privately by e-mail.

Comment: @IaroslavBlagouchine Thanks. It would be nice to receive a preprint at felix@fisica.ciens.ucv.ve . I just added an addendum to my answer to give a link to your published paper. Congratulations.

Comment: @Felix I sent it to your e-mail. Let me know if you haven't received it.

Comment: @IaroslavBlagouchine Yes. I just checked my email. It's a long paper which involves a lot of work. Congratulations. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just for your information, I used a CAS without any success for the general case. However, I obtained some formulas.

For $p=2$,
$$\frac{1}{8} \left(-\gamma _1\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)+\gamma
   _1\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)-\sqrt{2} (\gamma +\log (8)) \left(\pi +2 \log
   \left(\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$
For $p=3$,
$$\frac{1}{36} \left(-2 \gamma _1\left(\frac{1}{12}\right)+\gamma
   _1\left(\frac{5}{12}\right)+2 \gamma _1\left(\frac{7}{12}\right)-\gamma
   _1\left(\frac{11}{12}\right)+12 \sqrt{3} \log (2) \log \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)+6
   \sqrt{3} \log (3) \log \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)-12 \sqrt{3} \log (2) \log
   \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)-6 \sqrt{3} \log (3) \log \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)-2 \gamma 
   \left(\pi +3 \sqrt{3} \left(\log \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)-\log
   \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)\right)\right)+\pi  \left(-3 \log (3)+\log (16)+12 \log
   (\pi )-16 \log \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$ For $p=4$,$$\frac{1}{16} \left(-\gamma _1\left(\frac{1}{16}\right)+\gamma
   _1\left(\frac{9}{16}\right)+16 \log (2) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \log
   \left(\sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right)-4 \pi  \log (2) \csc
   \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)-16 \log (2) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \log
   \left(\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right)+16 \log (2) \cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right) \log \left(\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)-\gamma  \left(\pi 
   \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+4 \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)
   \left(\log \left(\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right)-\log \left(\sin
   \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right)\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \log
   \left(\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)$$ In these formulas, $\gamma$ is the Euler constant and $\gamma_1$ is the  Stieltjes constant.

Comment: *Totally* off topic, but I've just noticed that $$n!= \int_0^1(-\ln x)^ndx= \bigg[\frac{d^n}{dk^n}\int_0^1x^{-k}dx\bigg]_{k=0}= \bigg(\frac1{1-k}\bigg)^{(n)}_{k=0}$$ and wanted to share this with you.

Comment: @Lucian. I knew it was off topic but I just wanted to provide something to the OP. On the other side, I am very happy by your answer and comments. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: LOL! No, I meant my comment! :-)

Comment: @Lucian That's is always a useful trick. Thanks.