# Parametrize line segments from $0$ to $ \sqrt{3} + i $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

How to parametrize a line from $0$ to $ \sqrt{3} + i $ ? it's already in the form $z = x+ iy$ and I have no idea what should be done in order to integrate it for the next part.
Help please

Comment: Is it supposed to be a straight line or any possible path?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's always easier to think of $\Bbb R^2$ instead of $\Bbb C$, there you have the parametrization $(\sqrt 3 t,t), 0\le t \le 1$.

Can you adapt it?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $\sqrt 3 + i = \rho e^{i\phi}$. Then $z = te^{i\phi}, t \in [0,\rho]$ is a possible parametrisation.

Comment: @T.Bongers It is something I've learned from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585960/improper-integral-of-log-x-operatornamesech-x