# Evaluating $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)^{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

To prove an integral result, I have got to evaluate $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)^{n+1}} \text{ where } n\in\Bbb N$$
But since I haven't got much knowledge on evaluating series of this kind, some help or clues would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: How does $n$ relate to $k$?

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: Even values of $n$ have results that may be expressed in terms of powers of $\pi$, while odd values of $n$ do not.

Comment: For $n=1$, it is the negative of Catalan's constant. The general formula seems to be $-2^{-2n-2}\left(\zeta\left(n+1,\dfrac 14\right)-\zeta\left(n+1,\dfrac 34\right)\right)$ according to [W|A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B%28-1%29%5E%7Bk%2B1%7D%7D%7B%282k%2B1%29%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D)

Comment: I found a post related to the Euler product [$\sum\limits_{n\ge 2}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)^{s+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1586027/721644).

Answer (score 2):

One way to find the special values of the Dirichlet beta function at the odd natural numbers is to relate it to the [Euler numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerNumber.html) through the Maclaurin series for the secant,

$$\sec(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n E_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n},\qquad|z|<\pi/2.$$

If we take the logarithmic derivative of

$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)+\sec\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)=\prod_{n=-\infty}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z}{4n-1}\right)\left(1-\frac{z}{4n+1}\right)^{-1}$$

we get

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi}{2}\sec\left(\frac{\pi z}{2} \right ) &=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{-\frac{1}{4n-1}}{1-\frac{z}{4n-1}}-\frac{-\frac{1}{4n+1}}{1-\frac{z}{4n+1}} \right ) \\ 
 &=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{(4n+1)^{k+1}}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{(4n-1)^{k+1}} \right ),\;\;|z|<\pi/2 \\
&\qquad\text{geometric series} \\ 
 &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2\beta(2k+1)z^{2k}, \\
&\qquad\text{switch the order of summation and notice cancellation}.
\end{align*}$$

We now have two series for $\frac{\pi}{2}\sec\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n E_{2n}\pi^{2n+1}}{2\cdot4^n(2n)!}z^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2\beta(2n+1)z^{2n}.$$

And upon equating coefficients we find that

$$\beta(2n+1)=\frac{(-1)^n E_{2n}\pi^{2n+1}}{4^{n+1}(2n)!},\qquad n\geq0.$$

Answer (score 1):

This actually $-\beta(n+1)$ (dirichlet beta function)
Thanks to everyone who helped

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)^{n+1}}x^k=-2^{-(n+1)} \Phi \left(-x,n+1,\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ where appears the Lerch transcendent function.

For the case where $x=1$, this reduces to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)^{n+1}}=2^{-2(n+1)} \left(\zeta \left(n+1,\frac{3}{4}\right)-\zeta \left(n+1,\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)$$ as given in comments.

Comment: And that's one of the definitions of the dirichlet beta function

Comment: @Perch. I know but it was just another way.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k + 1} \over \pars{2k + 1}^{n + 1}}\,\right\vert_{\ n\ \in\ \mathbb{N}}}
\\[5mm] = &
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \bracks{2\pars{2k + 1} + 1}^{\,n + 1}} +
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-1 \over \bracks{2\pars{2k + 2} + 1}^{\,n + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over 4^{n + 1}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{k + 3/4}^{\,n + 1}} -
{1 \over 4^{n + 1}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{k + 5/4}^{\,n + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &
\bbx{{1 \over 2^{2n + 2}}\bracks{\zeta\pars{n + 1,{3 \over 4}} -
\zeta\pars{n + 1,{5 \over 4}}}} \\ &
\end{align}
where $\ds{\zeta\pars{s,\alpha}}$ is the
[Hurwitz Zeta Functon](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E1).