# Evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/4} \ln\left(\ln\left(\cot\left(x\right)\right)\right) {d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I've seen this integral on a math page :
$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \ln\left(\ln\left(\cot\left(x\right)\right)\right) {d}x.$$
And I tried to solve it, like Vardi's integral, by substituting $u=\ln\left(\cot(x)\right)$

The bounds are :
$u\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\ln\left(\cot\left( \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)=\ln(1)=0$
and $u(0)=\ln\left(\cot\left( 0\right)\right)=+\infty$ and this explains the minus sign we'll have it when we'll substitute
$$u=\ln\left(\cot(x)\right) \Longleftrightarrow du=-\frac{dx}{\cos x\sin x}.$$

The problem now is just to simplify this expression I did a lot of attempts but I didn't get something ! I think that the substitution is false, any tips or thoughts ?

Comment: Please [don't use `\frac` in exponents or limits of integrals](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189). It looks bad and confusing, and it rarely appears in professional mathematics typesetting.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Sure, I'll edit it right now ! Thanks for the advice tho :D

Comment: @Angelo Your edit collided with OP's one.

Comment: You substitution leads to solve another very difficult integral  $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} \log (u) \text{sech}(u) \, du=\frac{1}{4} \pi  \log \left(\frac{4 \pi ^3}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4}\right)$$

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 It doesn't :'( I tried the same steps with more intuition and I didn't get a result !!

Comment: Isn't this integral same as the Vardi's integral after substituting $y = \pi/2  -x $?

Comment: This seems useful so I'll link it here. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585960/improper-integral-of-log-x-operatornamesech-x)