# Evaluate $\int_{1}^\infty \frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to evaluate:
$$\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{1+x^2} dx$$

I've been told by the user Jack D'Aurizio that I can connect it to Euler's Beta Function using the substitution $x=e^u$ and using Feynman's Technique. I've tried connecting it to $$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}}dt $$ but I don't see anything. Would appreciate a hint to put me in the right direction.

Comment: This is known as *Vardi's integral*. There are many references outside this community, and even it was dealt with in the following posting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121545/evaluating-int-01-log-log-left-frac1x-right-fracdx1x2