# Can $ \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln ( \sin(x)) \; dx$ be evaluated with "complex method"?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Can the following integral be evaluated using complex method by substituting $\sin(x) = {e^{ix}-e^{-ix} \over 2i}$?
$$ I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln ( \sin(x)) \; dx = - {\pi \ln(2) \over 2}$$

Comment: Are you sure you want to compute $I$ using "complex method"?

Comment: I know how to calculate it with the other method. I'm just looking if it can be done. I don't have necessity to do it.

Comment: Nice question (+1)

Comment: @Chris'sister thank you ... :D

Comment: Are you sure your lower limit of integration is correct? I don't see much hope for it as $x\to 0^+$ though.

Comment: This can be done with complex analysis, using the same exact method as my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58654/integrate-square-of-the-log-sine-integral-int-0-frac-pi2-ln2-sinx/119877#119877).

Comment: @NickStrehlke many thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note first that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} \ln(\sin t)\,dt
&= 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin t)\,dt + 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(-\sin t)\,dt \\
&= 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin t)\,dt + 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \Bigl(\ln(\sin t) + i\pi\Bigr)\,dt \\
&= 4I + \pi^2i
\end{align*}
and, using the substitution $z=e^{it}$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} \ln(\sin t)\,dx
&= \int_{|z|=1} \ln\left(\frac{z-1/z}{2i}\right)\,\frac{dz}{iz} \\
&= \int_{|z|=1} \frac{\ln(1-z^2)}{iz}\,dz - \int_{|z|=1} \frac{\ln z}{iz}\,dz + \int_{|z|=1} \frac{\ln(i/2)}{iz}\,dz.
\end{align*}

The first integral on the right is zero $\dots$ this is because $\ln(1-z^2)$ is analytic inside the unit disk and vanishes at $z=0$ so the singularity in the integrand there is removable (you need to shrink the circle of integration slightly to avoid the points $z=\pm1$ and then let the radius go to 1).

The second integral we do directly
$$ \int_{|z|=1} \frac{\ln z}{iz}\,dz = \left[\frac{1}{2i}\bigl(\ln z\bigr)^2\right]_{-1^+}^{-1^-} = \frac{1}{2i}\Bigl[(\pi i)^2 - (-\pi i)^2 \Bigr] = 0
$$
where $-1^\pm$ indicate points just above and below $-1$ and on either side of the branch cut of $\ln$ along the negative real axis.

The third integral is just $2\pi i\ln(i/2)/i = 2\pi\bigl(-\ln2 + \pi i/2\bigr)$.

Therefore $4I + \pi^2i = -2\pi\ln2 + \pi^2i$ and $I = -\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2$.

Comment: Nice! Would you mind writing a little more explanation of the step where you split the integral into three parts?

Answer (score 4):

Let us change variables $u=\sin^2(x)$, $x=\arcsin(\sqrt{u})$, $\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{u(1-u)}}$:
$$
   \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin(x)) \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} \ln(u) \cdot \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{u(1-u)}} \stackrel{u=1-v}{=} \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \ln(1-v) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\sqrt{v(1-v)}}
$$
Adding two last integrals, and dividing by $2$:
$$
 \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin(x)) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{u(1-u)}\right)}{\sqrt{u(1-u)}} \mathrm{d}u  = -\frac{1}{4} \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\operatorname{B}\left(s,s\right)\right|_{s=\frac{1}{2}}
$$
Since $\operatorname{B}\left(s,s\right) = \frac{\Gamma(s)^2}{\Gamma(2s)}$:
$$
   \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\operatorname{B}\left(s,s\right) = 2 \operatorname{B}\left(s,s\right) \left(\psi(s) - \psi(2s)\right)
$$
where $\psi(s)$ is the digamma function.  Using $\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right) = \pi$, and duplication identity for the digamma function:
$$
    2 \psi(2s) = \psi(s) + \psi\left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right) + 2 \log(2) \quad \stackrel{s=\frac{1}{2}}{\implies} \quad \psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - \psi(1) = -2\ln(2)
$$
Combining, we arrive at the result:
$$
  \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin(x)) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \pi \cdot \left(-2 \ln(2)\right) = -\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(2)
$$

Comment: The OP explicitly requested a method using complex integration...

Answer (score 2):

Consider a known formula (which can be proved by the identity of $\sin x$ you mentioned):

$$
\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{j}{n}\pi\right)=\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}\quad n\geq 2,
$$
which implies that
$$
\frac{\pi}{2n}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\ln \left(\sin\frac{j}{n}\pi\right)=\frac{\pi}{2n}\ln (n)-\frac{\pi\cdot (n-1)}{2n}\ln 2.
$$
Now taking the limit on both side as $n\to\infty$, you get what you want by recognizing that the left hand side is a Riemann sum.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\sin x) d x = & \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(\frac{e^{x i}-e^{-x i}}{2 i}\right) d x \\
= & \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(e^{x i}-e^{-x i}\right) d x-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (2 i) d x \\
= & \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(e^{x i}\left(1-e^{-2 x i}\right)\right) d x-\frac{\pi}{2} \ln (2 i) \\
= & \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x i d x+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(1-e^{-2 x i}\right) d x-\frac{\pi}{2} \ln (2 i) \\
= & \frac{\pi^2}{8} i+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(1-e^{-2 x i}\right) d x-\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\ln 2+\frac{i \pi}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

For the remaining integral, let $y=e^{-2xi}$ yields

$$
\begin{aligned} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(1-e^{-2 x i}\right) d x&=\frac{1}{2 i} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\ln (1-y)}{y} d y \\
&  =\frac{1}{2 i}\left[-\operatorname{Li_2}(1)+ \operatorname{Li_2}(-1)\right] \\
& =-\frac{1}{2 i}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)\\&=\frac{i \pi^2}{8}
\end{aligned}
$$
Summing them up reaches the conclusion that

$$\boxed{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln (\sin x) d x =-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2}$$