# how integrate $\int\ln(1+\tan x)\,dx$ or $\int\ln(\sin x)\,dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

[image]

I integrate by part I assume $dx=dv$ and $\ln(\sin x)= u$ or
I compute by Maple but its answer wasn't clearly (Maple answer: `xln(1-exp((2I)x))+xln(sin(x))+(1/2*I)x^2+(1/2*I)*polylog(2, e((2*I)*x))`) 
thanks for any hints

Comment: Your formatting has gone astray. Can you please correct? Regards

Comment: Do you have bounds?

Comment: I pasted Integral(log(sin(x)),x) into wolframalpha.com to get a result. The solution contained something called polylogarithm.

Comment: whats polylogarithm ? how wolframalpha.com compute it?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: According to Mathematica the answer is 
$$ -x \text{Log}\left[1-e^{2 i x}\right]+x \text{Log}[\text{Sin}[x]]+\frac{1}{2} i \left(x^2+\text{PolyLog}\left[2,e^{2 i x}\right]\right) $$
Where PolyLog is [Polylogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). Of course this is a [non elementary integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). But for certain bounds, you find that the [integral converges](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189590/can-int-0-pi-2-ln-sinx-dx-be-evaluated-with-complex-integral) to some interesting  values.

Comment: If you know about [Clausen function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function), the results can be much simpler.

Comment: You posted an image. Please use latex and make the post searchable... Thanks.