# What is $\int\log(\sin x)~dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I know that the value of the integral of $\cot(x)$ is $\log|\sin x|+C$ .

But what about:

$$\int\log(\sin x)~dx$$

Is there any easy way to find an antiderivative for this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a representation of the antiderivative of $\log(|\sin x|)$ in terms of elementary functions, so no. You can however do this by using the power series expansion for $\log$ and integrate term by term if you are willing to toss aside elementary functions.

Comment: However, the integral under consideration can be expressed in a closed form.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function  SEE ALSO journal page 17, (pdf page 9), of http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.bams/1183548588

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such antiderivative can be written using elementary functions.

Rather than $\log (\sin x)$, let us consider the equivalently difficult $\log (\cos x)$.

Using integration by parts, we find:

$$\int \log(\cos x) = x\log(\cos x) + \int x \tan x dx$$

Now, finding the antiderivative means tackling $x \tan x$, and this latter expression has no antiderivative with elementary functions. This result follows from a theorem of Liouville (see, e.g., [here](http://math.hunter.cuny.edu/ksda/papers/churchill.pdf)) and the specifics of the argument for $x \tan x$ can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108598/is-xtanx-integrable-in-elementary-functions/108616#108616).

Comment: The cite "One can (easily) produce an elementary diﬀerential ﬁeld extension of the rational function ﬁeld R(x) containing arctan x (we are assuming the standard
derivative), but not one with no new constants. Indeed, it is not hard to show
that 1/(x^
2 + 1) cannot be written in the form (i) of the statement Theorem
5.3 (see p: 598 of [Ros2]). This indicates the importance of the no new constant
hypothesis in the statement of Liouville’s Theorem" . Could you explain how this implies your claim?

Comment: If you are asking about specifics for $\int x \tan x dx$ then I suggest you click on the latter link, where it is dealt with explicitly.

Comment: I did it and cited that sourse.

Comment: Peter Mueller refers to the article difficult to access.

Comment: @user64494, see pages 17-18 in http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.bams/1183548588 and then, if you can find it, the follow-up article mentioned, http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=719313

Comment: @WillJagy:you refer to J. Milnor, Hyperbolic geometry: The first 150 years.

Comment: @user64494, the first item is a link to that as a pdf. Milnor also wrote a follow-up concentrating on the integral this question asks about (except with an extra 2), the correct title is at the ams.org link.

Comment: @WillJagy: Are you serious? See the review in [ZBMath](http://zbmath.org/). "Milnor, John On polylogarithms, Hurwitz zeta functions, and the Kubert identities" should be inserted.

Comment: @user64494, I'm just showing references. I do not know if any discuss the nature of the integral as far as elementary functions. Also, I have not seen Milnor's paper  "On polylogarithms, Hurwitz zeta functions, and the Kubert identities." But mostly, I was able to give a link where the first paper could be downloaded as a pdf, and i did not want to type in the whole title for the second. It is just in case people wanted to look.  I'm not sure what part was less than serious; but it is alright if you feel I did not do my part correctly. I would have answered if I knew more.

Answer (score 2):

The indefinite integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. However the definite integral from $0$ to $\pi/2$ (or $\pi$) can be avalauted as shown below. $$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin(x)) dx = - \dfrac{\pi \log2}2$$
The above can be evaluated as follows. We have
$$I=\underbrace{\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin(x)) dx = -\int_{\pi/2}^0 \log(\cos(y)) dy}_{y = \pi/2-x} = \int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\cos(x))dx$$
Hence,
$$I+I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin(x)) dx + \int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\cos(x)) dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin(x) \cos(x))dx$$
Hence,
$$2I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin(2x))dx - \dfrac{\pi}2 \log2 = \dfrac12\int_0^{\pi} \log(\sin(x)) dx - \dfrac{\pi}2 \log2 = I - \dfrac{\pi}2 \log2$$
Hence, we get that
$$I = -\dfrac{\pi}2 \log2$$

Comment: This is interesting, but this does not deal with the question under consideration, is not so?

Comment: You may be interested in posts about this here http://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/solution-to-pow-10-another-hard-integral/ and here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58654/integrate-square-of-the-log-sine-integral-int-0-frac-pi2-ln2-sinx; both source this particular integral to an exercise in "Complex Analysis, third edition" (Ahlfors, p. 160).

Answer (score 2):

using $$\ln \sin x =-\ln 2-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}, \ x \in [0,\pi].$$

$$\int \ln(\sin x)dx=-\ln(2)\int dx-\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n}\int (\cos 2nx)dx$$

$$=-\ln(2)\cdot x-\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\sin(2nx)}{2n^2}+\mathcal{C}$$

Answer (score 0):

The Maple command $$ int(ln(abs(sin(x))), x); $$ outputs $$i\ln  \left( 2 \right) \ln  \left( {{\rm e}^{ix}} \right) -i\ln 
 \left( {{\rm e}^{ix}} \right) \ln  \left( {\frac {-i \left(  \left( {
{\rm e}^{ix}} \right) ^{2}-1 \right) {\it signum} \left( \sin \left( x
 \right)  \right) }{{{\rm e}^{ix}}}} \right) -1/2\,i \left( \ln 
 \left( {{\rm e}^{ix}} \right)  \right) ^{2}+i\ln  \left( {{\rm e}^{ix
}} \right) \ln  \left( {{\rm e}^{ix}}+1 \right) +i{\it dilog} \left( {
{\rm e}^{ix}}+1 \right) -i{\it dilog} \left( {{\rm e}^{ix}} \right) 
. $$

PS. The Mathematica command $$ Integrate[Log[Abs[Sin[x]]], x, Assumptions -> x > 0\, \&\& x < Pi/2]
 $$ outputs $$Piecewise[{{I [Pi] x - x Log[1 - E^{2 I x}] + x Log[Sin[x]] + 
    1/2 I (x^2 + PolyLog[2, E^{2 I x}]), 
   Sin[x] < 0}}, -x Log[1 - E^{2 I x}] + x Log[Sin[x]] + 
  1/2 I (x^2 + PolyLog[2, E^{2 I x}])] .$$

PPS. Because the formulatian of the question under consideration was edited from $\int \ln|sin(x)|\,dx$ to $\int \ln(sin(x))\,dx$ after my answer, I would like to add that the Maple command $$ int(ln(sin(x)), x) $$ outputs it in a closed form $$-x\ln  \left( 1-{{\rm e}^{2\,ix}} \right) +x\ln  \left( \sin \left( x
 \right)  \right) +1/2\,i{x}^{2}+1/2\,i{\it polylog} \left( 2,{{\rm e}
^{2\,ix}} \right)
  .$$

Comment: What is the meaning of 'signum' and 'dilog'? I never heard it before.

Comment: These are standard notations: see [dilog](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dilog) and [signum](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=signum) for info.