# Today a student asked me $\int \ln (\sin x) \, dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Calculate the integral
$$\int \ln (\sin x) \, dx.$$

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that the function isn't real-valued, so any result is necessarily going to be complex.

Comment: Does you student know about [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is $\int\log(\sin x)~dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504983/what-is-int-log-sin-xdx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following.
\begin{align}
I &= \int \ln(\sin(x)) \ dx 
\end{align}
can be evaluated by integration by parts and leads to
\begin{align}
I &= x \ln(\sin(x)) - \int x \ \cot(x) \ dx \\
&= x \ln(\sin(x)) -x \ln(1 - e^{ix}) - \frac{i}{2} \left( x^2 + \operatorname{Li}_2(e^{2ix}) \right)
\end{align}
where $i =\sqrt{-1}$ and $\operatorname{Li}_2(z)$ is the dilogarithm function.  It is of note that
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin(x)) \ dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \ln(2).
\end{align}