# Double integral $ \iint\ln(\sin(u-7v)) \,du\,dv$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Can you please help me solve this double integral?

$$ \iint_D\ln(\sin(u-7v))\,du\,dv $$ where
$$D:=\left\{(u,v)\;:\; 0\le u \le \pi \;,\; 0\le v \le \frac u7\right\} .$$

I know it's not possible to solve $\int \ln(\sin(x))$ but definite integral is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By replacing the variable $v$ with $t:=u-7v$, we get 
$$\int_{u=0}^{\pi}\int_{v=0}^{u/7}\ln(\sin(u-7v))\,du\,dv=
\frac{1}{7}\int_{t=0}^{\pi}\int_{u=t}^{\pi}\ln(\sin(t))\,du\,dt\\
=\frac{1}{7}\int_{t=0}^{\pi}\ln(\sin(t))(\pi-t)\,dt=\frac{I}{7}=\fbox{$-\frac{\pi^2\ln(2)}{14}$}$$
where $I=\int_{t=0}^{\pi}t\ln(\sin(t))\,dt=-\frac{\pi^2\ln(2)}{2}$.
In fact
$$I=\int_{t=0}^{\pi}\ln(\sin(t))(\pi-t)\,dt=\pi\int_{t=0}^{\pi}\ln(\sin(t))\,dt-I$$
which implies
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{t=0}^{\pi}\ln(\sin(t))\,dt=\pi\int_{t=0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(t))\,dt=-\frac{\pi^2\ln(2)}{2}$$
where in the last step we used [Today a student asked me $\int \ln (\sin x) \, dx.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794916/today-a-student-asked-me-int-ln-sin-x-dx)

Answer (score 0):

Did not it help you if rewrite it this way?

$$\int_0^\pi du \int_0^{\frac{u}{7}} \ln(\sin(u-7v))\,dv$$