# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$ complex integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate: $$2\cdot\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} dx$$

Using Complex Integration.

I want to do something with the unit circle, but I am not quite sure how to work-around with the unit circle and the integral.

Will someone have an idea?

Thanks =)

Comment: The answer is already here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/119877/131872 (similar integral).

Comment: You have already asked the same question in disguise, with $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\sin t\,dt.$$