# $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log^2(\cos^2x)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi^3}6+2\pi\log^2(2)$???

Tags: integration

I saw in a paper by @Jack D'aurizio the following integral
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log^2(\cos^2x)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi^3}6+2\pi\log^2(2)$$
Below is my attempt.

$$I=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\log^2(\cos x)\mathrm{d}x$$
Then we define
$$F(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log^2(a\cos x)\mathrm{d}x$$
So we have
$$F'(a)=\frac2a\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(a\cos x)\mathrm{d}x$$
Which I do not know how to compute. How do I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: "The trap is set, now we wait (for Jack)."

Comment: Substitute $\cos x=t$ and use the derivatives of Beta function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$I(a)=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} (\cos^2 x)^a dx$$

Hence we need $I''(0)$.

Now recalling the definition of Beta function we get $$I(a)=\frac 12 B\left(a+\frac 12 ,\frac 12\right)=\frac {\sqrt {\pi}}{2}\frac {\Gamma\left(a+\frac 12\right)}{\Gamma(a+1)}$$

Hence we have $$I''(a) =\frac {\sqrt {\pi}}{2}\frac {\Gamma\left(a+\frac 12\right)}{\Gamma(a+1)}\left(\left[\psi^{(0)}\left(a+\frac 12 \right)-\psi^{(0)}(a+1)\right]^2 +\psi^{(1)}\left(a+\frac 12 \right)-\psi^{(1)}(a+1)\right) $$

Substituting $a=0$ in above formula yields the answer.

Comment: A much more general result:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^\alpha(x)\cos^\beta(x)\log^n(\sin^\gamma(x))\log^m(\cos^\delta(x))dx=\gamma^n\delta^m\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\right)^m\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right)^n\left[\frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{1+a}{2})\Gamma(\tfrac{1+b}{2})}{2\Gamma(\tfrac{a+b}{2}+1)}\right]_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\beta)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Differentiation of the Beta function is a viable approach, but since we are dealing with a *squared* logarithm and not higher powers, it is faster to just exploit [the Fourier (cosine) series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos) of $\log(\cos^2\theta)$ and Parseval's theorem. Given

$$-\log(\cos^2\theta)=2\log 2+2\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\cos(2k\theta),\tag{1} $$
since $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(2jx)\cos(2kx)\,dx =\frac{\pi}{4}\delta(j,k)$, we immediately have
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log^2(\cos^2\theta)\,d\theta = 2\pi\log^2 2+\pi\zeta(2).\tag{2}$$

Since the LHS equals $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{4\log^2 x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$, we have just found the value of the hypergeometric series
$$ 8\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n(2n+1)^3}=8\cdot\phantom{}_4 F_3\left(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};\tfrac{3}{2},\tfrac{3}{2},\tfrac{3}{2};1\right)\tag{3} $$
which also equals $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log^2(1+t^2)}{1+t^2}\,dt$ or $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2(x)}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx$.

Comment: Yeah you're gonna have to explain this a bit more

Comment: @ClementC.: of course, now fixed.

Comment: OK, I have a dumb question. You get $\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k\geq 1} \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^2=2\pi\zeta(2)$ for the second term by Parseval, don't you? (or did I mess up with one factor there?)

Comment: @ClementC. the factor $2$ in $(1)$ gives that $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(2\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\cos(2k\theta)\right)^2\,d\theta = 4\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\zeta(2)=\pi\zeta(2).$$

Comment: @JackDAurizio Ah. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: you mean \begin{align} \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(1+t^2)}{1+t^2}\,dt\end{align} ?

Comment: @FDP: right, fixed that too.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}J=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln^2\left(\cos x\right)\,dx\end{align}

Observe that,

\begin{align}I&=4J\\
J&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln^2\left(\sin x\right)\,dx\\
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\sin x\right)\,dx&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left(\cos x\right)\,dx
\end{align}

(change of variable $y=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x$  )

\begin{align}
K&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln^2 \left(2\sin x\cos x\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln^2 \left(\sin\left(2x\right)\right)\,dx\\
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $y=2x$,

\begin{align}
K&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi} \ln^2 \left(\sin x\right)\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln^2 \left(\sin x\right)\,dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\pi \ln^2 \left(\sin x\right)\,dx\\
\end{align}

In the latter integral perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x$ and recall $\sin\left(\pi-x\right)=\sin x$ for $x$ real,

\begin{align}
K&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln^2 \left(\sin x\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln^2 \left(\cos x\right)\,dx\\
&=J
\end{align}

On the other hand,

\begin{align}
K&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\ln 2+\ln(\sin x)+\ln(\cos x)\right)^2 \,dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln^2 2+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln^2(\sin x)\,dx+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln^2(\cos x)\,dx+2\ln 2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\cos x)\,dx+\\
&2\ln 2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin x)\,dx+2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin x)\ln(\cos x)\,dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln^2 2+2J+4\ln 2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\cos x)\,dx+2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin x)\ln(\cos x)\,dx\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}L&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x^2}\,dx\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $x=\tan y$,

\begin{align}L&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln^2\left(\tan x\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\ln\left(\sin x\right)-\ln\left(\cos x\right)\right)^2\,dx\\
&=2J-2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin x)\ln(\cos x)\,dx\\
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}K+L&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln^2 2+4J+4\ln 2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\cos x)\,dx
\end{align}

Therefore (recall $K=J$),

\begin{align}J&=\frac{1}{3}L-\frac{\pi}{6}\ln^2 2-\frac{4}{3}\ln 2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\cos x)\,dx\end{align}

On the other hand,

\begin{align}L&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x}\,dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x}\,dx\end{align}

In the latter integral perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$,

\begin{align}L&=2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x}\,dx\end{align}

But it is well known that,

\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x^2}\,dx&=\frac{\pi^3}{16}\\
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\cos x)\,dx&=-\frac{1}{2}\pi\ln 2
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}J&=\frac{\pi^3}{24}-\frac{\pi}{6}\ln^2 2-\frac{4}{3}\ln 2\times -\frac{1}{2}\pi\ln 2\\
&=\boxed{\frac{\pi^3}{24}+\frac{1}{2}\pi\ln^2 2}\\
\end{align}

PS:
See: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2942594/186817

(in this post i assume only the value of $\zeta(4)$ )

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n+1} x^{n+1} =\frac{\log^2(1-x)}{2}$$ with $x \mapsto \sin^2 x$. and hence on integrating we obtain $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log^2(\cos^2 x) dx = \pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n-1}}{n4^n}{2n\choose n}=\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n4^n}{2n\choose n} -\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^24^n}{2n\choose n}$$ since the latter series $\mathcal{LS}$ is known whose value is $\displaystyle \zeta(2)-2\log^2(2)$ which is easily do able by computing the following integral $$2\int_0^1 \log\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt {1-x}+1}\right)\frac{dx}{x}=\zeta(2)-2\log^2(2)$$. Below I have derived the generating function for $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1}{2n\choose n}\frac{y^n}{n^24^n}$
[image]
and to evaluate the former series $\mathcal{FS}$, we use the elementary integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{n-1} \log(1-x)dx =-\frac{H_n}{n}$ and generating function of central binomial coefficients $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{x^n}{4^n}{2n\choose n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}-1$ which we too use to calculate the latter series. Now, we just need to divide both sides by x, multiply $\log(1-x)$ and integrating from 0 to 1 gives $$-\mathcal{FS} =\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)}{x\sqrt{1-x}}dx-\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}dx=4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\log(x)}{1-x^2} dx+\zeta(2)$$  since $$\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)}{x\sqrt {1-x}} dx=2\int_0^1\frac{\log\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)}{x\sqrt{1-x}}dx\stackrel{\rm \sqrt{1-x}\mapsto x}{=}4\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}{1-x^2}dx=-\frac{\pi^2}{2}$$ so $$\displaystyle -\pi\mathcal{FS}=\frac{\pi^3}{3},\; \pi\mathcal{LS} =\frac{\pi^3}{6}-2\pi\log^2(2)$$ and hence $-\pi\mathcal{FS}-\pi\mathcal{LS} =\frac{\pi^3}{6}+2\pi\log^2(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Getting rid of the first roadblock:**

Use the fact that $$\log(a\cos x) = \log a + \log\cos x$$
along with [the result that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690644/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-log-cosx-mathrmdx/690705#690705)
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \log\cos x\,dx = -\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2
$$
to get 
$$
F'(a) = \frac{\pi\log a}{a} -\frac{\pi}{2a}\log 2 
$$

Comment: Of course, one of the proofs of the intermediary result is [due to Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1403301/75808).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{I \equiv
> \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^{2}\pars{\cos^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
> {\pi^{3} \over 6} + 2\pi\ln^{2}\pars{2}:\ {\LARGE ?}}$.

\begin{align}
I & \equiv
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^{2}\pars{\cos^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ \pi/2\ -\ x}{=}\,\,\,
4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^{2}\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\left.4\,\Re\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}\ln^{2}\pars{{1 - z^{2} \over 2z}\,\ic}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.4\,\Im\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}\ln^{2}\pars{{1 - z^{2} \over 2z}\,\ic}\,{\dd z \over z}
\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}
\\[1cm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,
-\, 4\,\
\overbrace{\Im\int_{1}^{\epsilon}\ln^{2}
\pars{1 + y^{2} \over 2y}\,{\dd y \over y}}^{\ds{=\ \large 0}}
\\[2mm] & \phantom{\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,} -
4\,\Im\int_{\pi/2}^{0}\bracks{\ln\pars{1 \over 2\epsilon} + \pars{{\pi \over 2} - \theta}\ic}^{2}\,\ic\,\dd\theta
\\[2mm] & \phantom{\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,}
-4\,\Im\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - x^{2} \over 2x} + {\pi \over 2}\,\ic}^{2}{\dd x \over x}
\\[1cm] & =
4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\bracks{\ln^{2}\pars{2\epsilon} -
\pars{{\pi \over 2} - \theta}^{2}}\,\dd\theta
-4\pi\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - x^{2} \over 2x}
{\dd x \over x}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}
\bracks{2\pi\ln^{2}\pars{2\epsilon} - {\pi^{3} \over 6}} -
\bracks{4\pi\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x^{2}} \over x}\,\dd x -
4\pi\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\ln\pars{2x} \over x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{2\pi\ln^{2}\pars{2\epsilon} - {\pi^{3} \over 6}} -
\bracks{2\pi\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x +
2\pi\ln\pars{\epsilon}\ln\pars{4\epsilon}}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0}{\to}
\bbx{{\pi^{3} \over 6} + 2\pi\ln^{2}\pars{2}} \approx
8.1865
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x =
> -\,\mrm{Li}\pars{1} = -\,{\pi^{2} \over 6}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Noting that $$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln ^{2}\left(\cos ^{2} x\right) d x=4 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln ^{2}(\cos x) dx
$$

Let $$
I:=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln ^{2}(\cos x) d x \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{\pi}{2}-x}{=} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln ^{2}(\sin x) d x
$$

Using the identity $$[\ln (\sin x)+\ln (\cos x)]^{2}+[\ln (\sin x)-\ln (\cos x)]^{2}
=2\left[\ln ^{2}(\sin x)+\ln ^{2}(\cos x)\right],$$

we have $$
4 I=\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln ^{2}\left(\frac{\sin 2 x}{2}\right)}_{J} d x+\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln ^{2}(\tan x) d x}_{K}
$$
For the first integral, using $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\sin x) d x=-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \ln 2$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
J &=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}[\ln (\sin 2 x)-\ln 2]^{2} d x \\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln ^{2}(\sin 2 x) d x-2 \ln 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\sin 2 x) d x +\frac{\pi \ln ^{2} 2}{2} \\
& \stackrel{x\mapsto 2x}{=}  \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln ^{2}(\sin x) d x-\ln 2 \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln (\sin x) d x+\frac{\pi \ln ^{2} 2}{2} \\
& \stackrel{symmetry}{=}  I-\ln 2(-\pi \ln 2)+\frac{\pi \ln ^{2} 2}{2} \\
&=I+\frac{3 \pi \ln ^{2} 2}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
For the second integral, letting $y=\tan x $
and using the [post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-we-find-the-exact-value-of-displaystyle-int_-0-infty-frac-ln-2-x-1-x-2-d-x-tag?ch=17&oid=111431770&share=c2946aac&srid=CCOmo&target_type=question), yields $$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^{2} y}{1+y^{2}} d y=\frac{\pi^{3}}{8},
$$

then
$$
4I=I+\frac{3 \pi  \ln ^{2} 2}{2}+\frac{\pi^{3}}{8} \Rightarrow I=\frac{\pi^{3}}{24}+\frac{\pi \ln ^{2} 2}{2}
$$

Hence
$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln ^{2}\left(\cos ^{2} x\right) d x= \frac{\pi^{3}}{6}+2 \pi \ln ^{2} 2}$$

Comment: creative! thanks (+1)