# Analytical expression for integral

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve the integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi\text{ } \text{ln}(|\cos(\phi)|)^2
$$
I was wondering if the analytical expression of this integral is known. With mathematical tools like Mathematica I can only find the numerical expression which is equal to $8.18649$.

Without the squaring it can be solved:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \text{ ln}(|\cos(\phi)|) = -2\pi\ln(2) 
$$

Comment: Mathematica evaluates $\int dt \ \ln^2(\cos(t))$,  to very long expression. Similarly, she finds $\int\limits_0^{\pi/2} dt \ \ln^2(\cos(t))= (\pi^2 +3 \ln^2(4))\pi/24 $, and your integral is 4 times that

Comment: This is straightforward if you know about the Beta function. Reduce it to the 0–>pi/2 integral and let u=cos phi

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58654/1118406